# Android java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit Convert Milliseconds to Minutes

Tags: android, time

Is there a way to convert milliseconds to minutes using java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625433/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-x-mins-x-seconds-in-java/625624#625624) seems to suggest that you can use a `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes()` method, and the documentation suggests that you could use the `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert()` method with `TimeUnit.MINUTES` - the problem is that neither `TimeUnit.MINUTES` or `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes()` seem to actually exist.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe TimeUnit might have added minutes in 1.6: [1.6 docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#MINUTES), [1.5 docs](http://life.csu.edu.au/java-doc/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html)

Comment: Assuming this is about Android, that doesn't help. It seems to be based on the 1.5 APIs.

Comment: True, but it does explain the discrepancy.  Probably in Android need to implement your own extension.

Comment: Ah, you're very right. When the linked comment referred to '1.6' I assume it meant Android 1.6 - I probably should have known that. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, For Java versions below 1.5 or for systems that do not fully support the TimeUnit class (such as Android before API version 9)

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do from ms to minutes is divide by 60000. Why not just do that>

Comment: Because it is easy to screw up, by say, typing 600000, and using TimeUnit makes it clear what dividing by 60000 is supposed to be doing.

Comment: You can do the division by (60 * 1000), which makes it clearer.

Comment: Yeah, I've resorted to doing doing it milliseconds / (60 * 1000) style. But I'm doing this for lots of units (I'm going from milliseconds to minutes, days, hours and weeks) so if there was a prettier way to do it I would prefer it.

Comment: If you're doing it a lot, write your own utility methods (in the style of TimeUnit), rather than having `(60 * 1000)` all over the place.