# How to run service in background every 10 minute?

Tags: android

I want to use a service that run in background indefinitely and call a method every 10 minute
and its running even app killed

How to create it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android run thread in service every X seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230606/android-run-thread-in-service-every-x-seconds)

Comment: May I ask why? The reason I'm asking is because many times in Android, you have multiple ways of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

You can do by using service as follows

```
@Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //performe the deskred task
        }
    }, 10minutes time in milisecods);

      // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
      return START_STICKY;
  }
```

This service will get started automatically even if app get killed, and postdelayed will run

Comment: is it safe to use Handler inside Service ?

Comment: It does not run the code every 10 Minutes with this code.
It will run the code in 10 minutes only once.

Answer (score 0):

For "how to work with services", see 
[Services - Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)
[Services in Android - Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)
Here is a clear solution that focus on "every 10 minutes" part using AlarmManager: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10222390/2591556

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a Running Service

User AlarmManager to run Service every 10 minutes

```
   AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent i = new Intent(context, YourService.class);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 600000, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
     }
```

Comment: `RTC_WAKEUP` doesn't work with `Service`. You would have to use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` to do this

Comment: Kindly explain, it's for starting pending intent through alarm manager and it is verified and working. But its have been 2 years since initially posting many things came in between on Android.

Answer (score 0):

you could write a background Service: 
[Running in a Background Service](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html)

and start the service every 10-11 min (cause of AlarmManager power saving behaviour), or with exact timing (needs to shedule next execution every time) with [AlarmManager.setExact](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Example:

```
private static PendingIntent createClockIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context.getString(R.string.widget_broadcast_clock_update));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 1,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        return pendingIntent;
    }

    public static void startClockAlarm(Context context) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        clockIntent = createClockIntent(context);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, 0,
                600000, clockIntent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Alarm manager which will be called after every 10 mins

```
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Random random = new Random();
        int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
        notificationIntent.setClass(this,AlarmReceiver_.class);
        notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");

        PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(YourClass.this, m, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 300000L,
                600000L, broadcast);
```

ManiFest receiver Code where you will get a receiver response

```
<receiver android:name="com.yourpackage.AlarmReceiver_"

        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

You will have to create Receiver where you will receive data as an above-specified name of AlarmReceiver_.class