# How to run the background service in Android O, every minute?

Tags: android, service, background-service, android-jobscheduler, android-workmanager

I have an old application in which the service was invoked using the `AlarmManager`'s `setExact` every minute, but in the latest **Android O**, it is not allowing me to run the service in the same way. I couldn't use foreground service because I don't want to show any notification when my service is running.

I want help on tweaking my application architecture in a way so that my code should run in the Android O with minimum changes.

When I run my application in the Android, it is crash:(.Please find the stack trace of the crash below.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.***.***.***ControllerApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.***.***.qa/com.***.***.services.AlarmService
```

Edit:

The task in my application is time critical therefore I used `setExact` in `AlarmManager` but none of the currently supported APIs is scheduling jobs at an exact time. With that said, *If I use JobScheduler/ WorkManager then my application will malfunction.*

Comment: use job Scheduler

Comment: Use job scheduler or work manager

Comment: Work manager is in alpha and job scheduler cannot schedule a job at the exact time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28062440/how-to-run-service-in-background-every-10-minute/52477512#52477512

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Alarm manager which will be called after every 10 mins

```
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Random random = new Random();
        int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
        notificationIntent.setClass(this,AlarmReceiver_.class);
        notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");

        PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(YourClass.this, r5, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 300000L,
                600000L, broadcast);
```

ManiFest receiver Code where you will get a receiver response

```
<receiver android:name="com.yourpackage.AlarmReceiver_"

        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

You will have to create Receiver where you will receive data as an above-specified name of AlarmReceiver_.class

Comment: I am already using the AlarmManager to repeat the job, the problem is starting the jobs using the AlarmManager is throwing exception in Android O.

Comment: Can you show me how you are calliing an Alarm Manager?

Comment: @SyedTarufNaqvi Your issue solved, if not then let me know.