# Schedule Asynctask - While? Service? Timer?

Tags: android

Ok, I got a `Togglebutton` that starts a `service`. The service starts a new `Thread` in `onStartCommand`. In this Thread  an `Asynctask` is executed.

Now I want this `Asynctask` to be executed for example every 5 seconds. The `Asynctask` checks if the website is available. 
-> if no, after 5 secs check again
-> if yes, show message and stop

Whats the best method with my already present code:

```
public class NotifiyService extends Service {

    String savedsa;
    Thread Th1;
    boolean value;


    final class TheThread implements Runnable{
        int serviceID;
        String savedsa1;
        TheThread(int serviceID,String savedsa){
            this.serviceID = serviceID;
            this.savedsa1 = savedsa;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            HttpTaskParams httpparams = new HttpTaskParams(value,savedsa1);
            new HttpTask().execute(httpparams);
            }
    }
    public NotifiyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences7 = getSharedPreferences("Prefsa",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        savedsa = sharedPreferences7.getString("keysa","");
        Toast.makeText(NotifiyService.this,getResources().getString(R.string.MonStarted)+ "\n" + savedsa,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Th1 = new Thread(new TheThread(startId,savedsa));
        Th1.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        //super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(NotifiyService.this,getResources().getString(R.string.MonStopped), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        return null;
    }

    private static class HttpTaskParams{
        boolean value;
        String address;

        HttpTaskParams(boolean value, String address){
            this.value = value;
            this.address = address;
        }

    }

    private class HttpTask extends AsyncTask<HttpTaskParams,Void,Boolean>{

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(HttpTaskParams... params) {
            boolean value = params[0].value;
            String address = params[0].address;

                try {
                    URL url = new URL(address);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                    httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                    httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(3000);
                    httpURLConnection.connect();
                    value = true;
                    return value;
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    value = false;
                    return value;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    value = false;
                    return value;
                }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean  result) {
            if(result){
                Toast.makeText(NotifiyService.this,"true",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //Notification in Status Bar
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(NotifiyService.this);
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.dummy);
                Intent intent = new Intent(NotifiyService.this, Main2Activity.class);
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(NotifiyService.this,0,intent,0);
                builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                builder.setLights(Color.YELLOW,600,600);
                builder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
                builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dummy));
                builder.setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.newNotify));
                builder.setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.newNotify2));
                builder.setAutoCancel(true);
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(1,builder.build());

            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(NotifiyService.this,"false",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
            ScheduledExecutorService checkreg = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
            scheduledFuture = checkreg.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    HttpTaskParams httpparams = new HttpTaskParams(value, savedsa1);
                    new HttpTask().execute(httpparams);
                }
            }, 0, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);}

@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        //super.onDestroy();
        Th1.interrupt();
        scheduledFuture.cancel(false);
        Toast.makeText(NotifiyService.this,getResources().getString(R.string.MonStopped), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        stopSelf();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a `ScheduledExecutorService` could help you. 
Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8232889/5930286) answer.
Please let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Hey, yes it worked with that thanks :-) But now I have another "issue". It won´t stop. My togglebutton starts and stops the service but it seems the thread is still running. I´ve read that `Thread.stop` isn´t so good. Do you have an advice?

Comment: To properly stop the `scheduleTaksExecutor`, keep the result of the `scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(...)` in a variable, and call the `cancel` method of this result (for example in the onDestroy of your Service). Does this help?

Comment: I understand what you mean, but don´t know how to get a result from scheduleatFixedRate( ).

Comment: `ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(...);`
`scheduledFuture.cancel(false);`
The cancel method: cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning).
I'm sorry, it should be scheduledExecutorService, not scheduleTaskExecutor.

Comment: Hey, after 2 busy days I tried your solution and it works. Thx a lot :-)

Answer (score 1):

try this /**
 * Loads exchange rates form network periodically
 * Returns results in broadcast message.
 * Created by koss on 19.02.16.
 * */
public class EcbEuropeService extends Service {

```
public static final String ECB_URL = "http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml";
public static final int UPDATE_PERIOD = 30000;
public static final int UPDATE_TICK = 1000;

public static final String NOTIFICATION = "koss.ru.oneclickrate.receiver";
public static final String EXTRA_CURRENCIES_MAP = "extra_currencies_map";

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    getUrlData();
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public Cubes getUrlData() {
    (new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cubes>() {
        Map<CurrencyType, BigDecimal> result = new EnumMap<CurrencyType, BigDecimal>(CurrencyType.class);

        @Override
        protected Cubes doInBackground(Object... params) {
            Cubes cubes = new Cubes();
            InputStream is = null;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(ECB_URL);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                cubes = EcbEuropeResponseParser.parse(is);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if(urlConnection!=null) IOUtils.close(urlConnection);
                if(is!=null) IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
                return cubes;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cubes map) {
            super.onPostExecute(map);
            sendBroadcastMessage(map);
            startTimer();
        }
    }).execute();
    return null;
}

/**
 * Restarts timer
 * */
public void startTimer() {
    cdt.cancel();
    cdt.start();
}

CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(UPDATE_PERIOD, UPDATE_TICK) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    }

    public void onFinish() {
        getUrlData();
    }
};

private void sendBroadcastMessage(Cubes currenciesMap) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(NOTIFICATION);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CURRENCIES_MAP, currenciesMap);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

}