# Android: lifecycle of AlarmManager on BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, lifecycle

I want to wake an activity on a specific time. To do so, I (also) registered AlarmManager on a Boot complete BroadcastReceiver.

As far as I know, only the Service can last forever to be alive in the background to wake an Activity. Activities and BroadcastReceiver can die on inactivity.

The following code I have doesn't run a service. However, it seems like it's working (Alarm works even if I launch it after 24 hours). Is this safe? Or should I launch a service?
If this is safe to use, what's the logic behind this? why is AlarmManger created by BroadcastReceiver doesn't get destroyed by Android lifecycle manager?

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            registerAlarm(context);
        }
    }

    private void registerAlarm(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am =(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
        long nextAlarm = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000; //Some time later.
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextAlarm, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this safe?

`AlarmManager` does not care what sort of `PendingIntent` you use.

Users may or may not appreciate an activity appearing out of nowhere, but that is a separate issue.

> As far as I know, only the Service can last forever to be alive in the background to wake an Activity.

Services do not last forever.

> Activities and BroadcastReceiver can die on inactivity.

No. Your *process* can "die on inactivity", which includes all components in that process.

> why is AlarmManger created by BroadcastReceiver doesn't get destroyed by Android lifecycle manager?

Because `AlarmManager` is a system service, maintained by the OS, not by your app.

Answer (score 0):

Services can be killed by Android anytime. For a detailed analysis on the options available to trigger recurring tasks or long running tasks on android, take a look at this thread - [Scheduling recurring task in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376470/scheduling-recurring-task-in-android/)