# Callback method for hour Change in Android

Tags: android

I want to create a live wallpaper that respond to time change like if the time is 18:00 it should change to night wallpaper.Is there any callback method for checking hour change

Comment: @Pragnani what code could be relevant to this question?

Comment: @Niek code in the sense, what he has tried till know...he started question "I want to create" so, I have asked for his code that he tried till now

Answer (score 1):

Schedule a recurring task in Android and set the initial delay to the time difference between the current time and 18:00 hours. To learn about scheduling recurring tasks take a look at this thread - [Scheduling recurring task in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376470/scheduling-recurring-task-in-android)

I suggest you use an `AlarmManager`. Take a look at the [methods inside the class related to scheduling](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can use AlarmManager to set a pendingintent to be fired at any time you want. 
You can then grab the intent in a broadcast receiver and update your wallpaper.