# How would I check calendar time without abusing battery/RAM?

Tags: android, time, calendar

I'm trying to call a method on a specified time by the user. For example, "at 4:00pm- send a message to Bob".

I understand how to get the `calendar.HOUR()`, `calendar.MINUTE()`, etc; however, I'm unsure where to place this code. I want to make sure the method calls on the right time, but I also don't want to have to update the `calendar time` every second (for fear of too much battery usage of RAM).

I'm currently using this, which is in the `onCreate` method.

```
    if (calendarHour == startHour && calendarMinute == startMinute)
{
//do stuff
}
```

Is there a standard on how to check what time is it without spamming? What code would I use and where do I place it?

Comment: this might be of use to you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376470/scheduling-recurring-task-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

```
Calendar cal; // set your desired time
PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getService( /*  register a service that "sends a message to Bob"*/ );

final AlarmManager am = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE).
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), operation);
// you can close your app now.
```