# Scheduling a task for certain days of the week in Android

Tags: android

As the title implies, I'm looking to schedule a task to run on certain days at certain times. For example, I might have it run at 5:00 every Tuesday and Thursday. I've seen [several scheduling methods for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376470/scheduling-recurring-task-in-android), but all of them seem to operate in the form of "do task after n delay" or "do task every n seconds".

Now I could probably jury-rig it by having it calculate the time to the next execution during the execution of the task itself, but that seems inelegant. Is there some better way to do this?

Comment: Have you read: http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: use alarm managers it will solve your problem.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I did, but it doesn't do exactly what I'd like. It seems that I'll probably end up using the AlarmManager to schedule a task for each day and have it recur every week. Or maybe do like I mentioned in the original question.

Answer (score 3):

You've to set an Alarm to perform those tasks. Most probably you will end up calling a Service once the alarm is triggered:

```
private void setAlarmToCheckUpdates() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        if (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)<22){
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22);
        } else {
                calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);//tomorrow
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22); //22.00
        }

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), ReceiverCheckUpdates.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, myIntent,0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

However, if you need to set specifically a day:

```
int weekday = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);  
if (weekday!=Calendar.THURSDAY){//if we're not in thursday
    //we calculate how many days till thursday
    //days = The limit of the week (its saturday) minus the actual day of the week, plus how many days till desired day (5: sunday, mon, tue, wed, thur). Modulus of it.
    int days = (Calendar.SATURDAY - weekday + 5) % 7; 
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, days);
}
//now we just set hour to 22.00 and done.
```

Above code is a little bit tricky and mathematic. If you wan't something stupid aswell as easy:

```
//dayOfWeekToSet is a constant from the Calendar class
//c is the calendar instance
public static void SetToNextDayOfWeek(int dayOfWeekToSet, Calendar c){
    int currentDayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            //add 1 day to the current day until we get to the day we want
    while(currentDayOfWeek != dayOfWeekToSet){
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
        currentDayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    }
}
```