# Android detect date change event

Tags: android

I found only broadcast event for date change "android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED"
But It is only working when user manually change the date.

**Please suggest some default broadcast for the problem.**

My other alternatives to achieve that can be : **But m ignoring these things**

- Alarm - to be triggered at exact 12:00 am for all days.(But need to
  take care all time zones
- My own repeating task : That will keep on checking if current date
  has changed from previous saved one.

Would appreciate any solution for the same from some official sources.

Answer (score 2):

Yes `android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED` action has been raised when user changes the date.
I think you are trying to set an alarm for daily (that you are handling Date change action). But this is not a solution. You need to set daily alarms. Like

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

---

To do repeating task there are some ways, read more at [Scheduling recurring task in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376470/scheduling-recurring-task-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But as I mentioned I would like to ignore using Alarm.These are my last options to achieve that.

Comment: @ArpitGarg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376470/scheduling-recurring-task-in-android Read it