# how to run huge tasks in Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

Is there a way to set below tasks in android ?
Is Alarm Manager the best choice?

Monday, Tuesday, Thursday

06:45

```
Airplane mode OFF
Silent mode OFF
Data traffic (3G) ON
```

08:20

```
Silent mode ON
```

11:55

```
Silent mode OFF
```

12:45

```
Silent mode ON
```

16:15

```
Silent mode OFF
```

17:00

```
Wifi ON
Data traffic OFF
```

22:00

```
Wifi OFF
Airplane mode ON
Silent mode ON
```

Wednesday

06:45

```
Airplane mode OFF
Silent mode OFF
Data traffic (3G) ON
```

08:20

```
Silent mode ON
```

11:55

```
Silent mode OFF
```

12:45

```
Wifi ON
Data traffic OFF
```

22:00

```
Wifi OFF
Airplane mode ON
Silent mode ON
```

Friday

06:45

```
Airplane mode OFF
Silent mode OFF
Data traffic (3G) ON
```

08:20

```
Silent mode ON
```

11:55

```
Silent mode OFF
```

12:45

```
Silent mode ON
```

16:15

```
Silent mode OFF
```

17:00

```
Wifi ON
Data traffic OFF
```

22:00

```
Wifi OFF
Silent mode ON
```

23:45

```
Airplane mode ON
```

Saturday

09:30

```
Airplane mode OFF
Silent mode OFF
Wifi ON
```

23:45

```
Airplane mode ON
Silent mode ON
```

Sunday

09:30

```
Airplane mode OFF
Silent mode OFF
Wifi ON
```

22:00

```
Airplane mode ON
Silent mode ON
```

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376470/scheduling-recurring-task-in-android

Answer (score 0):

yes i think too that using Alarm Manager and pending intent is the best Way.
 you should set these times in alarm manager and and put a number (for example number or other data variable)  in putextra (in pending intent) for decision.  after raise time, alarm manager open activity or class and with Number in the getextra,  decide which situation should be change .

alarm manager -- > set time1 & make pendingintent to Executeactivity & putextra "1"

alarm manager -- > set time2 & make pendingintent to Executeactivity & putextra "2"

in activity act similar way :

```
Executeactivity activity{

string Desition = getextra data from current intent ; 

if(Desition  == "1"){
-------
}
 if(Desition == "2"){
 ------
}
```

i hope that was useful .

Answer (score -1):

before I write a problem like this,I think AlarmManager can complete it very well,