# my Android service won't keep running

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-asynctask, android-service

I have a service that performs an AsyncTask which calls itself after each completion. As you'll see below, I am starting my service in the foreground. It starts successfully and keeps running as intended while I have it plugged into my computer and spitting output to LogCat. I know this because to test, I have my AsyncTask loop spitting out a notification every 5 minutes. However, when I unplug it from my computer, the notifications don't come! It's as if the service just completely stops after I start it!

NOTE: My service is a regular service, not an IntentService.

Here is my onStartCommand...

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    getData(intent);
    self = this;

    // Enter foreground state
    String title = "Service started.";
    String subject = "Service is running.";
    String body = "Monitoring...";
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, title,
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    if(notificationSounds)
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    else
        notification.sound = null;
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity3.class);
    PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, subject, body, pendIntent);
    startForeground(1500, notification);

    new BatteryLifeTask(appContext).execute();
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Here is my AsyncTask:

```
// Looping AsyncTask for continuous mode
private class BatteryLifeTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    // Member variables
    Context appContext;
    int batteryPct0;

    public BatteryLifeTask(Context context) {
        super();
        appContext = context;
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        System.out.println("Entering doInBackground");
        // Get the initial battery level
        batteryPct0 = getBatteryPercent();
        System.out.println("Initial battery percent: " + batteryPct0);

        // Check time
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date dateNow = c.getTime();
        // getTime returns ms, need minutes. 60000ms in a minute.
        long currTime = dateNow.getTime() / 60000;

        if(currTime >= timeToUse){
            finished = true;
            stopSelf();
        }

        System.out.println("Leaving doInBackground");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if(!finished) {
            int waitTime = 60000 * interval; // 1 minute is 60000 miliseconds
            System.out.println("Entering postExecute. waitTime is " + waitTime);
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(!finished) { // In case postDelayed is pending, avoids extra notification
                        System.out.println("An interval has passed.");
                        calculateHelper(batteryPct0);
                        new BatteryLifeTask(appContext).execute();
                    }
                }
            };
            Handler h = new Handler();
            h.postDelayed(r, waitTime);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my code for creating notifications:

```
// Method for creating a notification
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
void notify0(int id, String title, String subject, String body, boolean playSound){
    NotificationManager NM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notify = new Notification(android.R.drawable.
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0);
    notify.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), subject, body, pending);
    if(playSound)
        notify.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    else
        notify.sound = null;

    // Cancel running notification if exists
    NM.cancel(id);

    // Push notification
    NM.notify(id, notify);
}
```

Can anyone help me? This is driving me insane! My app works PERFECTLY when plugged in and hooked up to USB debugging. But when unplugged, the service seems to completely halt and do nothing.

Comment: unrelated, but instead of `// 1 minute is 60000 miliseconds`, you can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#MINUTE_IN_MILLIS

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks, that's helpful. Use an alarmmanager for what? how will that help?

Comment: @njzk2 is right: `AlarmManager` is the way to go rather that this looping `AsyncTask`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14377875/603270

Comment: @shkschneider Does the AsyncTask go to sleep / can it be killed by the OS? I need it to run indefinitely without interruption. AlarmManager can do this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return `START_STICKY` instead of `START_NOT_STICKY` and review your design. In your case it's better to use the AlarmManager with a 5 minute timeout and then start an IntentService.

Comment: waitTime in my app can be set up to 3 hours. Part of the design is to get the battery level at the start at the 3 hours, and at the end of the 3 hours and find the difference to get the battery used within that interval. It's part of a prediction algorithm. Will this 5 minute timeout interfere with this?

Comment: Set the alarm manager timeout whatever you want, but set a timer with the alarm manager and manage it. In this way you avoid any battery drain.

Comment: Can you maybe provide an example of a task completed with an alarmmanager? Also, does it have a pre/post execute? I need the code that is currently in doInBackground to be executed and completed before the code within postExecute. I saw that AsyncTask had this functionality, which is why I chose to use it in my design.

Comment: docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html With the alarm manager the system send to your app an intent you catch it with a broadcast receiver when the timeout expires and then you can start an intentservice. An intentservice works in background so you don't need to worry about anything.

Comment: Other note: your design is wrong because the CPU can go to deep sleep without a wakelock but you really don't want that or you kill the user battery, so please please use the alarm manager.

Comment: ok. thanks. I'll try and figure out how to rework my design around it.

Comment: One more thing. You're saying I should change my service class to an IntentService? What's the reason for that?

Comment: You could use a normal service but an intentservice it's convenient in this case because it works in a background thread as an AsyncTask instead of running on the UI thread.

Comment: Ok. So I'm incredibly confused on how to do this. I need to place the following in a loop that runs in the background: Calculate initial battery, wait an interval, calculate ending battery. The only place i see alarmmanager fitting in is handling the wait and then starting an intentservice that calculates the ending battery which doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68422/discussion-between-greywolf82-and-jayb).

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are returning [START_NOT_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_NOT_STICKY) on the Service's [onStartCommand()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29).

> **START_NOT_STICKY** if this
>   service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from
>   onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), and there are no new start intents
>   to deliver to it, then take the service out of the started state and
>   don't recreate until a future explicit call to
>   Context.startService(Intent).

You should return [START_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) instead

> **START_STICKY** If this service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), then
>   leave it in the started state but don't retain this delivered intent.
>   Later the system will try to re-create the service.

Check this [service api changes](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2010/02/service-api-changes-starting-with.html) especially the section of Service lifecycle changes.