# Does Xamarin.Forms support periodic background tasks?

Tags: xamarin, backgroundworker, xamarin.forms

I am having a difficult time finding documentation on background tasks support for Xamarin.Forms.
Does Xamarin.Forms provide support for periodic background tasks?

I need to implement this for both Windows Phone 10 and Android.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

XF has no implementation for background tasks. You will need to implement these natively. Below are examples on how to do it for each type of project.

**UWP**

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTask

**Android**
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_2_android_services/

**WinRT**

https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/05/01/background-tasks-in-windows-store-apps.aspx

**iOS**

Just for those that want iOS as well.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_3_ios_backgrounding_techniques/

**Xamarin.Forms**

Going into more detail for each section is https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-background-tasks/

Comment: the Xamarin Help link contains old code.  Is there a newer example that you are aware of?

Answer (score -5):

Yeas, but it depends what you need to do.

You can for example use System.Threading.Timer (.net class) is Activity/Service

```
private System.Threading.Timer timer;
```

In Activity OnCreate

```
TimeSpan timerTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1000);
            timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new System.Threading.TimerCallback(OnTimerFired), null, timerTime, timerTime);
```

In Activity OnDestroy

```
if (timer != null)
            {
                timer.Change(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
                timer.Dispose();
                timer = null;
            }


private void OnTimerFired(object state)
{
    Do some periodic job
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I actually want to run a task in the background when my app isn't loaded.

Comment: So you can either use your own auxiliary service in background, which will run continuously and will "managed" the main application.

or some "scheduler"
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376470/scheduling-recurring-task-in-android

Answer (score -5):

I use Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer Method, it starts a recurring timer using the device clock capabilities. While the callback returns true, the timer will keep recurring.

http://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer/