# Android wont let me enter to an endless loop

Tags: java, android

Hi im trying to do an app that searchs bluetooth devices that are near every 5-10 seconds, so I tried to do an endless loop but the app is getting stuck when I press the button that starts the loop:

```
int stopInt=2;
serachB.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    do {
                        final Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                listAdapter.clear();
                                getPairedDevices();
                                startDiscovery();

                            }
                        }, 4000);

                    } while (stopInt>1);
                }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "the app is getting stuck"? As in, an endless loop? Sounds like what you're attempting

Comment: You should decrement the stopInt variable in some place. Until it will result in infinite loop

Comment: CubeJockey- it freezes up and after a while get terminated, Shriram- can you please give me an example, I didn't understand

Comment: "How to create an unresponsive App." You shot yourself in the foot by looping infinitely on the GUI-Thread. Just start some recurring scheduling in the onClick. See https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html and for example https://guides.codepath.com/android/Repeating-Periodic-Tasks and http://stackoverflow.com/a/14377875/982149

Comment: `while (stopInt>1);` end less loop, stopInt is always > 1

Answer (score 1):

```
private final Handler mMyhandler = new Handler();

private final Runnable checkBluetoothRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        //Do your work here

        mMyHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
    }

};

serachB.setOnClickListener(
    new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
          mMyhandler.post(checkBluetoothRunnable);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it this way:

```
serachB.setOnClickListener(
    new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while(true){
                        listAdapter.clear();
                        getPairedDevices();
                        startDiscovery();
                        Thread.sleep(4000);
                    }
                } 
            });
        }}
```

Comment: Noooooo , no, don't! Spin-Wait is an anti-pattern! Use some scheduling technique.

Comment: @Fildor of course you're right. Just like you shouldn't do such a heavyweight procedure every 4 seconds (which if I remember right discovers for 12 secs anyway)

Comment: That's also correct. But that does not make suggesting a spinwait better ;)

Comment: @Fildor I'm so lazy today bud. If he asked for a better solution maybe I'd posted it, but he asked for the loop to work :P

Comment: Fair enough. He has been warned now, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are continually creating new instances of `Handler` in your `while` loop which is going to eat up memory. I wouldn't be surprised if you were getting an `OutOfMemoryError` which is causing the termination. Try creating a single instance outside of your loop.

The `Runnable` passed to `Handler` runs on the `UIThread` since it was created on that thread. This should be avoided for lengthy operations and instead delegated to another thread.

> When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message
>   queue of the thread that is creating it

Also, rather than using the `Handler` class you could potentially swap it out to use `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` which will give you a pool of threads which can then periodically execute your device discovery code.

Firstly create a `ScheduledExecutorService`:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
```

Create an instance of your `Runnable`:

```
MyRunnable deviceDiscovery = new MyRunnable();
```

Then in your `onClick` method you kick off with `scheduleAtFixedRate`:

```
ScheduledFuture<?> future = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(deviceDiscovery, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Then when you want to stop it running you need to call `cancel` on the `ScheduledFuture`:

```
future.cancel(true); // Set to true to say it can interrupt if already running
```