# Android: Run a task on a certain date

Tags: java, android

Im looking for the best way to complete a certain task when a certain date is reached. What is the best way to a achieve this?

ie. 1st of each month I run command y

Comment: you should go through android dev docs before posting a question here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scheduling recurring task in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376470/scheduling-recurring-task-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

Use AlarmManager.  You'll also need a BroadcastReceiver for the BOOT_COMPLETED message so you can restart the alarm if the phone is rebooted.  TO calculate when the 1st day of the next month is, use the Calendar class-  get the Calendar for now, then add 1 to the month and set the day to 1.  Then you can convert that to ms for the alarm.

Comment: What about `JobScheduler` ? :

Comment: @Superman The problem with JobScheduler is that it doesn't promise to do a job at a specific time-  it promises to do it when a set of constraints are met.  Which for a timed job may actually get weird-  you can set a minimum delay, and a maximum delay, but it can fire at any time in that window.  I'm not sure what happens if you make mintime=maxtime, if that gives you a very small window or if it throws an exception for a bad builder.  ALthough it can persist things across reboots which may make it worth using to save a bit of effort there.

Comment: Again from the perspective of battery, wouldn't that be ideal ? :/

Comment: @Superman For a once a month task?  You're talking such a small energy difference I doubt you could measure it on an mutimeter.  Now its possible that for a once a month task the timing doesn't matter much either.  Hard to say without knowing all the details of the task.  I definitely wouldn't say using JobScheduler was wrong though.  Of course also note that JobScheduler is v21+.  v19 is still 20+% of the worldwide market.

Comment: I see thanks for the info, I forgot it was once in a month task :) . It seems Firebase job dispatcher is the same JobScheduler with backward compatibility , have you tried it ?

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android

Comment: btw, I've also sent a 'Hi' in Fb, not sure if it's your profile though :)