# Alarm manager with notification

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I have a function `public void notifiy()`
this function contains notification and plays sound which can be run while app is not running

my question is I want to call that function for example everyday when current time of device is 6:00 am I know it is done by Alarm Manager but how to call that function at a certain time checking the current time.

Answer (score 0):

you must use the Android [Alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) (AlarmManager)

> Alarms (based on the AlarmManager class) give you a way to perform time-based operations outside the lifetime of your application. For example, you could use an alarm to initiate a long-running operation, such as starting a service once a day to download a weather forecast

samples are provided by the official docs : [here](https://developer.android.com/shareables/training/Scheduler.zip)

EDIT: if you don't want to use the AlarmManager , you can use Timer or ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor as it's mentionned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14377875/5410373)

```
timer = new Timer();

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    synchronized public void run() {

        \\ here your todo;
        }

    }}, TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1), TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1));
```

ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor  is prefered to use :

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate
  (new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        // call service
     }
  }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```