# What solution is better for sync offline-mode app with server once a minute

Tags: android, android-workmanager, android-background

I've made Android app that uses offline-mode. Also it has button "Sync", on click - syncronization with server is performed (server is not Firebase-service DB).

I want to do the same sync without this button once a minute when my app is on foreground and when network connection is on.

WorkManager seems the best solution for the usecase, but according to [this article](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/recurring-work) minimum interval for WorkManager is 15 minutes.

Other ways described in [this article](https://developer.android.com/guide/background) are: ForegroundService, AlarmManager and background Thread.

Also I found solution [Sync Adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters)

What way would be the most efficient for the case?

P.S. I understand that this scenario is not very clean and probably the best would be add online-mode and switch between two modes without frequent syncs. But I have some reasons at this time not to do that

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I chose next way:

1. To invoke one-minute sync I used ThreadPool. [This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376470/scheduling-recurring-task-in-android?rq=1) helped me to choose.
2. Inside my Application class I put that code:

   ```
   val scheduler = Executor.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
   scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate({
       .... <My Sync Block> ....
   }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
   ```
3. To prevent getting the same data from the server (there could be huge pieces of data in my case), I had to use MD-5 alghoritm on the server-side. It works as follows:

   - server emits data with hashes (for each piece od data)
   - mobile app gets data and saved both data and hashes in SQLite. In next sync app sends hashes back in request
   - server looks if requested data has different hashes and includes only updated data in respond