# how to updating or send contents in android app

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, scheduled-tasks

I am new to android app development. I am currently designing an android app.I need to send data every day like messages(texts&images) to app user. I don't know to do that.So anyone can help me?

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376470/scheduling-recurring-task-in-android