# How to make a scheduling

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks

I want my application to trigger an event at a certain time and can be repeated on the chosen day. How to make a scheduling that can be set like what time the command can work and what days the command can be repeated again as needed?

Comment: Do you need an exact executing or is it not so important, it can be a little deffered? If it's first case then you need to use an AlarmManager, second case — WorkManager. A link https://developer.android.com/guide/background

Comment: yes because I want to make a schedule for the smartroom application so that the connected device can work according to the schedule that has been set

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scheduling recurring task in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376470/scheduling-recurring-task-in-android)

Comment: sorry it seems like it hasn't answered my question, I not really understand the explanation