# Create a Task Scheduler activity running only for a specific user and time in Windows 10

Tags: android-activity, task, scheduler

I need to create a Task Scheduler activity on Windows 10 that allows me to run a .bat script only when my user is connected and at 9 and 17 o' clock. Is it possible? I only see these two options separately. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scheduling recurring task in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376470/scheduling-recurring-task-in-android)