# Android: get time until Runnable is executed via Handler

Tags: android, time, handler, runnable

I have a timer in my app which shut's down the app implemented with a handler to which I post a delayed runnable "quit". When user clicks the timer icon it should also show how much time is left. How could I get this data?
Should I implement an object which would count the seconds and use that data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to use [ScheduledExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) with [ScheduledFuture](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html), these API are more efficient and powerful than Handler and Timer IMO:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
Runnable quitTask = new Runnable();

// schedule quit task in 2 minutes:
ScheduledFuture scheduleFuture = scheduledTaskExecutor.schedule(quitTask, 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

... ...
// At some point in the future, if you want to get how much time left:
long timeLeft = scheduleFuture.getDelay(TimeUnit.MINUTES);
... ...
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, this will cut the job.

Comment: Beware, [`TimeUnit.MINUTES` is not guaranteed to exist on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472423/android-java-util-concurrent-timeunit-convert-milliseconds-to-minutes)