# Android repeating task does not work

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, task, repeat, executorservice

can you help me?
I implemented an executor and scheduledWithFixedDelay, but it does it only once....
And I want to do this task in a repeating way...

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable(){

        public void run() {
            updateList();
        }

    }, updateTime, updateTime, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Beware, [`TimeUnit.MINUTES` is not guaranteed to exist on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472423/android-java-util-concurrent-timeunit-convert-milliseconds-to-minutes)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing it the right way. 
Which made me read at the java docs and here is what I found which I find surprising myself.

> If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent
>   executions are suppressed.

[ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)

Is there a chance that the code in the runnable produces an exception, which causes the Scheduled Executor to terminate execution? Surely you would've mentioned that?

But as I said I find this surprising to read as I thought that Scheduled Executor handles exceptions such that subsequent task execution is NOT suppressed. And that this is one of the main reasons to be preferred instead of the classic [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html). But now I see in the javadoc that I apparently thought wrong...

I am not very much familiar with Android platform, but maybe there is a difference in java.util.concurrent facilities between Oracle's JVM and Android's Dalvik so considering Oracle's JVM javadocs may not be a good idea after all.

EDIT:
Indeed the javadoc of the factory method says that

> (Note however that if this single thread terminates due to a failure
>   during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if
>   needed to execute subsequent tasks.)

[Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor%28%29)

EDIT2:
Oracle's and Dalvik's java doc seems to be practically indistinguishable.

Comment: The method updateList can run into an exception, but all exceptions which are possible are handled with try and catch.

Comment: What if you try with a very simple logic in the Runnable, something like just system.out.println("just been executed at " + new Date()). Also you could try with ScheduledExecutorService.newScheduledThreadPool(int corePoolSize) to see if the behavior is any different.

Comment: I know what the problem is now. In my method updateList() I wrote notifyDataSetChanged(). This should "notify" a datalist that something changed in the data. But with this method in my code the "task" never stops and so it cant start again....

Comment: Great! That's why I asked you to change the runnable's code to see if the problem is in the update() method or in the usage of Executor's framework.