# Object reference valid for a specified time

Tags: java, android

Is there some class in Java/Android to hold a object's reference for a specified time (1 minute for example) avoiding the garbage collector to pick the object for that time and allowing it after?

I want it to implement a memory cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Cache in Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained), which also works for Android. It probably gives you what you want.

For instance:

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
       .expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
       .build(
           new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
             public Graph load(Key key) {
               return createExpensiveGraph(key);
             }
           });
```

Comment: Beware, [`TimeUnit.MINUTES` is not guaranteed to exist on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472423/android-java-util-concurrent-timeunit-convert-milliseconds-to-minutes)