# Get data from internet every x minutes

Tags: java, android

I creating the phone tracking app, i want to get the data from the internet (actualy the latitude and longitude) from the device i tracked. the tracked phone is okay, they send the latitude and longitude every onLocationChanged executed to my database server.
And for the tracking phone app i can get that data but just when oncreate once. i get the data using asynctask, The problem is i having difficluties to get that data every X minutes, should i use handler ? can somebody here help me with some code ?

Here is my code so far

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final String Url = "http://mysite.com/tes.php";

    mf =(SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    gmap = mf.getMap();
    gmap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    gmap.setMapType(gmap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

    lat= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lati);
    longit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longi);



            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             lokasibaru lokasi = new lokasibaru();
            lokasi.execute(Url);


}
```

and this is my asynctask

```
private class lokasibaru extends AsyncTask <String,ArrayList<String>,ArrayList<String>>{

    String latitude,longitude;      

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {


            }
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> hasil) {

        latitude = hasil.get(0);
        longitude = hasil.get(1);
        lat.setText(latitude);  
        longit.setText(longitude);


        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... value) {
            ArrayList<String> result = null ;
            String Url = value[0];
            koneksi get = new koneksi();

            try {
                //result = GetR.getdata(Url);
                result = get.getdata(Url);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            return result;
        }

    }
```

and this is my koneksi class to get the data from internet

```
public class koneksi {

public ArrayList<String> getdata(String url) throws Exception{
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String data = null;
    ArrayList<String> kordinat = new ArrayList<String> ();
    int count ;
    try{
        HttpClient client= new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI site = new URI(url);
        HttpGet req = new HttpGet();
        req.setURI(site);
        HttpResponse resp = client.execute(req);
        count =0;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resp.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String l = "";
        String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        while ((l = in.readLine()) != null ){
        //sb.append(l+nl);
        kordinat.add(l);
        count++;
        }
    in.close();
    data = sb.toString();
    return kordinat;
    }
    finally{

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a handler

```
   private Handler m_handler = new Handler();
```

// ..............

```
Runnable m_handlerTask = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, Xmins);
             new lokasibaru().execute();
    }
};


private void startGettingDataTask()
{
    m_handlerTask.run(); 
}

private void stopGettingDataTask()
{
    m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask);
}
```

Call `startGettingDataTask()` to start and `stopGettingDataTask()` to remove the callbacks!

Comment: so where i supossed to invoke that code ? is it in OnCreate ? 
there are error on this code
`  m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, INTERVAL);`
it says " Cannot refer to a non-final variable m_handlerTask inside an inner class defined in a different method "

Comment: You call startGettingDataTask() in OnCreate() and stopGettingDataTask() in onPause() or onDestroy(). As for INTERVAL declare it as global variable or just add final at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Look into Android [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), within the service create a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) which  starts a [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) task that request the page and sends the location.

To the [ScheduledExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) you can pass the time interval like so,

```
//this will run the task every 5 minutes
scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

For below API 9

```
//this will run the task every 5 minutes
scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Beware, [`TimeUnit.MINUTES` is not guaranteed to exist on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472423/android-java-util-concurrent-timeunit-convert-milliseconds-to-minutes)

Comment: [TimeUnit](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) contains MINUTES since api 1 and everyone considers creating app above api 8.

Comment: No, `TimeUnit.MINUTES` and [`TimeUnit.toMinutes(long)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#toMinutes(long)) are only available at API 9 (when the switch from [Java 1.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#SECONDS) to [1.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#MINUTES) was made)

Comment: alright, get your point, but since OP didn't mention the api, so my answer is generic. AFAIK not most of the devs target below api 9.
I've updated the answer.