# extracting elements from a timestamp in java

Tags: java, android, datetime-format

If I am given a timestamp value such as: Tue Jun 22 18:17:48 +0000 2010, how can I extract the values "Jun 22" from the timestamp and turn it into a variable?

Comment: Is the timestamp example coming from a String?

Comment: not initially but It can be converted to a string though

Comment: @EdmundRojas see my post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427169/converting-a-date-string-into-milliseconds-in-java/8427764#8427764 . It uses `Calendar` to find the correct date.

Comment: It seems that you have got a `java.util.Date`? For new readers to the question see if you can avoid that. The `Date` class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` or another appropriate class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use pure java code to get this

```
    String input = "Tue Jun 22 18:17:48 +0000 2010";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d hh:mm:ss Z yyyy");
    Date date = sdf.parse(input);
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

OUTPUT: `Jun 22`

Comment: I like this answer if you need to do additional processing on the date, but if you only need to display it the parsing might cause a performance hit and so you'd want to stick with simple strings. Depends on your use case.

Comment: If what you want is the String "Jun 22" I would go with this answer.  If you're looking to actually process the data, you should use a Calendar object and then `get()` the `MONTH` and `DATE` fields from it.  Converting structured data into a string and then back into structured data should always be avoided.

Comment: @Avi Cherry can the timestamp be passed directly into that get object or must it be formatted first through another means?

Comment: No need to format anything, you can set a Calendar object's value from a Date object directly.  Typically you would call `Calendar myCal = Calendar.getInstance()` then `myCal.setTime(date)`. (I haven't a clue why there isn't a `getCalendar()` method that takes a Date as a param, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want it as a String, you can use:

```
String input = "Tue Jun 22 18:17:48 +0000 2010";
String monthAndDay = input.split("\\s+")[1] + input.split("\\s+")[2];
```

If it is coming as a date, check out my post from earlier today:

[converting a date string into milliseconds in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427169/converting-a-date-string-into-milliseconds-in-java/8427764#8427764)

Comment: this could be the answer I need!

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The idiomatic way to do it is by parsing the given date-time string into `OffsetDateTime` (as it has a timezone offset) and format the resulting `OffsetDateTime` into the `String` of the desired pattern.

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "Tue Jun 22 18:17:48 +0000 2010";
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM d H:m:s XX u", Locale.ENGLISH);

        ZonedDateTime odt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtfInput);

        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String result = dtfOutput.format(odt);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Jun 22
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/z9deLv)

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Example {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Tue Jun 22 18:17:48 +0000 2010";
    String[] parts = input.trim().split(" ");
    String monthAndDay = new StringBuilder()
      .append(parts[1]).append(" ").append(parts[2]).toString();
    System.out.println(monthAndDay);
  }
}
```