# Converting a time String to ISO 8601 format

Tags: java, string, time

I am trying to create a String in a format like **2015-08-20T08:26:21.000Z**
to **2015-08-20T08:26:21Z**

I know it can be done with some String splitting techniques, but i am wondering if there is an elegant solution for that (with minimal code changes).

Both of the above are time strings, the final one which i need is Date in ISO 8601 . https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6

I have tried a few similar questions like [converting a date string into milliseconds in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427169/converting-a-date-string-into-milliseconds-in-java) but they dont actually solve the purpose.

Also tried using :

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ");
String nowAsString = df.format(new Date());
```

But it still does not do any String to String conversions. Getting the following error:

**23:04:13,829 WARN  [RuntimeExceptionMapper]  caught RuntimeException: {}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date**

Is there some library which someone can suggest ?

Thanks.

Comment: Use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). See: [tag:jodatime]

Comment: input and output are both strings. But these strings actually represent different timezones.

Comment: A DateFormat does String to Date and Date to String conversion. You want String to String conversion. You can thus use a DateFormat to do String to Date conversion, and another one doing Date To String conversion. And no, they don't represent difference timezones. One has a millisecond part and the other doesn't. That's the only difference. The final Z means Zulu time, i.e. UTC timezone.

Comment: So org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter ?

Comment: @CodeMonkey So your goal is to eliminate the `.000`? Your title is confusing as both date-time strings in your first sentence are valid [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) strings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.parse( "2015-08-20T08:26:21.000Z" )
       .toString()
```

> 2015-08-20T08:26:21Z

## Date-Time Formatter

If all you want to do is eliminate the `.000`, then use date-time objects to parse your input string value, then generate a new string representation of that date-time value in a different format.

## ISO 8601

By the way, if that is your goal, the Question’s title make no sense as both strings mentioned in the first sentence are valid [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted strings.

- `2015-08-20T08:26:21.000Z`
- `2015-08-20T08:26:21Z`

## java.time

Java 8 and later has the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). These new classes supplant the old java.util.Date/.Calendar & java.text.SimpleDateFormat classes. Those old classes were confusing, troublesome, and flawed.

### Instant

If all you want is UTC time zone, then you can use the [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class. This class represents a point along the timeline without regard to any particular time zone (basically UTC).

### `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`

Calling an Instant’s [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toString--) generates a String representation of the date-time value using a [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT) formatter instance. This formatter is automatically flexible about the fractional second. If the value has a whole second, no decimal places are generated (apparently what the Question wants). For a fractional second, digits appear in groups of 3, 6, or 9, as needed to represent the value up to nanosecond resolution. Note: this format may exceed ISO 8601 limit of milliseconds (3 decimal places).

### Example code

Here is some example code in Java 8 Update 51.

```
String output = Instant.parse( "2015-08-20T08:26:21.000Z" ).toString( );
System.out.println("output: " + output );
```

> output: 2015-08-20T08:26:21Z

Changing to a fractional second, `.08`

```
String output = Instant.parse( "2015-08-20T08:26:21.08Z" ).toString( );
```

> output: 2015-08-20T08:26:21.080Z

If interested in any time zone other than UTC, then make a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object from that `Instant`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your format is just not right try this :-

```
try {
        String s = "2015-08-20T08:26:21.000Z";
         SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
    Date d = df.parse(s);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
        System.out.println(sdf.format(d));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Don't use 'Z'. Use X. The final Z means that this is a time is the UTC timezone. So the result is completely different. BTW, due to the presence of DST in your default timezone and the absence of DST in UTC, some Strings don't represent any existing date in the local timezone, but do in UTC.

Comment: @JBNizet that was useful , thanks i will edit the code

Answer (score 2):

Conversion of a date `String` of unknown formatting into a date `String` that uses known formatting can be accomplished using two `DateFormat` objects- one dynamically configured to parse the format of the input `String`, and one configured to generate the formatted output `String`. For your situation the input `String` formatting is unspecified and must be provided by the caller, however, the output `String` formatting can be configured to use ISO 8601 formatting without additional input. Essentially, generating an ISO 8601 formatted date `String` output requires two inputs provided by the caller- a `String` containing the formatted date and another `String` that contains the `SimpleDateFormat` format.

Here is the described conversion as Java code (I deliberately have left out null checks and validations, add these as appropriate for your code):

```
private String formatDateAsIso8601(final String inputDateAsString, final String inputStringFormat) throws ParseException {

     final DateFormat iso8601DateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH);
     iso8601DateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

     final DateFormat inputDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(inputStringFormat, Locale.ENGLISH);
     final Date inputDate = inputDateFormatter.parse(inputDateAsString);

     return iso8601DateFormatter.format(inputDate);
}
```

If you want to modify that method please note that `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread-safe, and that you should not use it from a static context without a workaround for multi-threaded code (`ThreadLocal` is commonly used to do just such a workaround for `SimpleDateFormat`).

An additional "gotcha" is the use of a `Locale` during the construction of the `SimpleDateFormat` objects- do not remove the `Locale` configuration. It is not safe to allow the system to choose to use the default `Locale` because that is user/machine specific. If you do allow it to use the default `Locale`, you run the risk of transient bugs because your development machine uses a `Locale` different than the `Locale` of your end-user. You do not have to use my selected ENGLISH `Locale`, it is perfectly fine to use a different Locale (you should understand the rules of that `Locale` and modify the code as appropriate however). Specification of no `Locale` and utilization of the system default is incorrect however, and likely will lead to many frustrating hours trying to diagnose an elusive bug.

Please understand this solution is not ideal as of Java 8 and the inclusion of the JodaTime based classes, like `Instant`. I chose to answer using the outdated API's because those were what you seemed concerned with in your question. If you are using Java 8 I strongly urge to learn and utilize the new classes as they are an improvement in almost every conceivable way.