# Convert string date into integer to insert date into sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, date, android-sqlite

I have a date picker in my app returning the date as `String` in the form **(yyyy-mm-dd)**. The problem I have is how to convert it from `String` to `Integer` or any other format to insert it into SQLite, that I can query it later.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
 String formattedDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to work with dates in Android SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363112/best-way-to-work-with-dates-in-android-sqlite)

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert the date string to milliseconds 
then you can do whatever you want to do with it from there, look at this stackoverflow answer 
[converting a date string into milliseconds in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427169/converting-a-date-string-into-milliseconds-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Inserting the date to sqlite could be done (even if it might not be good practice) as a string too. Sqlite is not too strict about types. Nevertheless, you could in theory convert the date to millis. Something like

```
 Date d = format.parse(<<Your Date String>>)
```

(see http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/SimpleDateFormat.htm) and then you insert into DB the

```
d.getTime()
```

For an explanation see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/date_gettime.htm.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.2 Date and Time Datatype
>
> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
>   and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
>   are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
>   values:
>
> TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"). REAL as Julian
>   day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November
>   24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar. INTEGER
>   as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>   Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these
>   formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and
>   time functions.

[See SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Date And Time Functions
[DateTime SQLite functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)