# Difference in time - from before midnight to after midnight without date

Tags: java, time

I am struggling to calculate time when going after midnight:

```
String time = "15:00-18:05"; //Calculating OK
    //String time = "22:00-01:05"; //Not calculating properly
    String[] parts = time.split("-");

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date date1 = null;
    Date date2 = null;
    Date dateMid = null;


    String dateInString = "24:00";
    try {
        dateMid = format.parse(dateInString);
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        date1 = format.parse(parts[0]);
        date2 = format.parse(parts[1]);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();


    if (date2.getTime()<date1.getTime()) //in case beyond midnight calculation
    {
        difference = dateMid.getTime()-difference;
    }



    int minutes = (int) ((difference / (1000*60)) % 60);
    int hours   = (int) ((difference / (1000*60*60)) % 24);

    String tot = String.format("%02d:%02d", hours,minutes);
    System.out.println("dif2: "+tot);
```

Comment: you could add a check where you verify that date 2 is before date 1. in that case, you can have something along the lines of 24h-(date1-date2) to find out the actual difference between date 1 and date 2

Comment: What about daylight saving times? 22:00-04:00 might be a difference of five, six or seven hours dependent on the day of the year.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The `Date` class is long outdated, and especially `SimpleDateFormat` is also notoriously troublesome. You may want to forget about those classes and instead use [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't care about daylight saving changes and you assume the world is ideal (which it isn't), you can just subtract the duration between end and start (treating `end` as the start and `start` as the end) from 24 hours:

```
String time = "22:00-01:05";
String[] parts = time.split("-");

LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse(parts[0]);
LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse(parts[1]);
if (start.isBefore(end)) { // normal case
    System.out.println(Duration.between(start, end));
} else { // 24 - duration between end and start, note how end and start switched places
    System.out.println(Duration.ofHours(24).minus(Duration.between(end, start)));
}
```