# java: summing LocalTimes difference

Tags: java, time, localtime

I have multiple working hours in LocalTime and I want to check if the time exceeds 24 hours.
The time is in 24h format.

For example:

1. 02:00 - 08:00
2. 10:00 - 12:00
3. 23:00 - 03:00

In the example above, it exceeds 24h since it starts at 02:00 and goes till 03.00.
It is only allowed to go till 02:00.

I implemented a loop and tried to calculate the time difference and sum it, for example:

1. 02:00 - 08:00 --> 6 h
2. 08:00 - 10:00 --> 2 h
3. 10:00 - 12:00 --> 2 h
4. 12:00 - 23:00 --> 11h
5. 23:00 - 03:00 --> 4 h

In total it would be 25h, so it is bigger than 24h.
However my problem is that I cannot calculate the time difference between 23:00 - 03:00 because LocalTime only goes till 23:59:59. So I currently I cannot calculate durations beyond a 24 hour period.

So using ChronoUnit won't work:

```
ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(23:00, 03:00);
```

I am not sure what kind of approach I should use to solve this problem

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49791495/difference-in-time-from-before-midnight-to-after-midnight-without-date/49792561#49792561) answer your question?

Comment: Just to clarify:  your input is a list of chronologically ordered LocalTime ranges?

Comment: @VGR yes this list is chronologically ordered

Comment: If the calculated difference comes out negative, you must have crossed midnight. In this case just add 24 hours to get the correct difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `LocalTime`, then you have to use `LocalTime.MIN` and `LocalTime.MAX` for an intermediate calculation of the minutes between critical time slots. You can do it like done in this method:

```
public static long getHoursBetween(LocalTime from, LocalTime to) {
    // if start time is before end time...
    if (from.isBefore(to)) {
        // ... just return the hours between them,
        return Duration.between(from, to).toHours();
    } else {
        /*
         * otherwise take the MINUTES between the start time and max LocalTime
         * AND ADD 1 MINUTE due to LocalTime.MAX being 23:59:59
         */
        return ((Duration.between(from, LocalTime.MAX).toMinutes()) + 1
                /*
                 * and add the the MINUTES between LocalTime.MIN (0:00:00)
                 * and the end time
                 */
                + Duration.between(LocalTime.MIN, to).toMinutes())
                // and finally divide them by sixty to get the hours value
                / 60;
    }
}
```

and you can use that in a `main` method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // provide a map with your example data that should sum up to 24 hours
    Map<LocalTime, LocalTime> fromToTimes = new HashMap<>();
    fromToTimes.put(LocalTime.of(2, 0), LocalTime.of(8, 0));
    fromToTimes.put(LocalTime.of(8, 0), LocalTime.of(10, 0));
    fromToTimes.put(LocalTime.of(10, 0), LocalTime.of(12, 0));
    fromToTimes.put(LocalTime.of(12, 0), LocalTime.of(23, 0));
    fromToTimes.put(LocalTime.of(23, 0), LocalTime.of(3, 0));

    // print the hours for each time slot
    fromToTimes.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("from " + k + " to " + v 
            + "\t==>\t" + getHoursBetween(k, v) + " hours"));

    // sum up all the hours between key and value of the map of time slots
    long totalHours = fromToTimes.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.summingLong(e -> getHoursBetween(e.getKey(), e.getValue())));

    System.out.println("\ttotal\t\t==>\t" + totalHours + " hours");
}
```

which produces the output

```
from 08:00 to 10:00 ==> 2 hours
from 23:00 to 03:00 ==> 4 hours
from 10:00 to 12:00 ==> 2 hours
from 02:00 to 08:00 ==> 6 hours
from 12:00 to 23:00 ==> 11 hours
        total       ==> 25 hours
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(LocalTime.of(23, 0), LocalTime.of(03,0)
```

this will give you -20, then you can do some math if the result is less then zero, means 24 -20 = 4, so using ChronoUnit can work, but better use LocalDateTime