# How to calculate the total number of days passed

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate date/time difference in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351483/calculate-date-time-difference-in-java)

I am providing the user with the option to select the date using Date Picker. Is there any in-built method using which I can calculate the duration in days wrt to user selected date and todays date.

Comment: no there is no inbuilt method. You have to write those 4 lines of code. It is frustrating :(

Comment: hey mate you have any such code which you have implemented earlier ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't like answering this because there were *millions* of questions like this (use search option before posting questions). Use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). There is a [`Period`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) class, which will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Get the difference between the two times in milliseconds. Than you can get the Days via Java's Calendar class.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date today = new Date(); // the date of today
Date target = new Date(); // the date of when the user picks

long todayEpoch = today.getTime(); // or can use = System.currentTimeMillis();
long targetEpoch = target.getTime();

long daysInMs = targetEpoch - todayEpoch; //days in MS's

//the # of days
float days = (daysInMs/1000/60/60/12);
```

Comment: Then go straight to Epoch, ether way the Date class works fine for this.

Comment: That's not going to account for bisextile years (366 days)