# How to find difference two dates on android app

Tags: android, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate date/time difference in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351483/calculate-date-time-difference-in-java)

I am a new on Android and I want to make a new app for me. I want to subtruct two dates (dd/mm/yyyy) format by using currentDate. For example I want to find the differences of the days between 01/02/2013 and currentDate. How can I do it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat dfDate  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    java.util.Date d = null;
    java.util.Date d1 = null;
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    try {
            d = dfDate.parse("01/02/2012 ");
            d1 = dfDate.parse(dfDate.format(cal.getTime()));//Returns 15/10/2012
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    int diffInDays = (int) ((d.getTime() - d1.getTime())/ (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    System.out.println(diffInDays);
```

Check [Ex1](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/FindtheDifferenceBetweenTwoGivenDates.htm) and [Ex2](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/90.html) for more detailed example

Comment: 01/02/2013 date is fix date but I dont want to fix current date in my code by hand. I want that when I run the app, it takes the current date from system and it calculate dhe diffirences. How can I get the current date from system and fix in the code?

Comment: i changed the code, check it again

Comment: thanx so much. i hope it runs

Comment: That's fine buddy. enjoy the day

Comment: when I run this code I face the null pointer exception. why?

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look into [DateUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html), that offers some utility methods to compute elapsed time between two dates, but only for representation. Do not use the direct approach to convert between days/milliseconds since it does not take into consideration leap years, leap seconds, summer/winter time changes, etc. Those considerations are handled by Calendar classes.

**Update**
You can use [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library to perform relative date and time calculations like the one you need.