# Convert String to date to calculate the difference

Tags: java, string, date

I have 2 dates in a String format (ex. 2012-04-23, 2012-03-08), and I want to find the difference between them.

What is the best way to calculate that in Java?

I am just concerned with the date and not the time

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351483/calculate-date-time-difference-in-java

Comment: How do you want to represent difference? min/hours/days...

Comment: Maxim Shoustin: I am just concerned with the date and not the time

Comment: @Dooree I posted method for your question. Use joda time, its easy ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert string to date using:

```
String dateString = "2012-04-23";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").parse(dateString);
```

You can read about SimpleDateFormat further [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

---

As to difference between two dates, you can calculate it in milliseconds with:

```
int milliseconds = dateOne.getTime() - dateTwo.getTime();
```

`getTime()` returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970.

To convert it in days, use:

```
int days = milliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
```

Comment: @EdwardRuchevits and what about diff in weeks/years/month? Your technic is not good for that since you dont know how many days in month 29/30/31.

Comment: Weeks? Divide `days` by **7**. Years? Divide `days` by **365.242**. Isn't it obvious? About months, well, it wil be more complicated.

Comment: The days between logic can fail on a day light savings boundary, because one day is 23 or 25 hours

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to add a third party jar to your project, then check the [jodatime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

- Convert string to date -  [`DateTimeFormat`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)

> DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
>
> DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(your-string);

- Find the difference between them -[`interval`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_interval.html)

> Interval interval = new Interval(time1, time2);

You also might want to check the difference between interval and duration which are concepts in jodatime lib

Answer (score 1):

Use SimpleDateFormat to turn the strings into Date objects and use the getTime() method on Date to get the equivalent time in milliseconds.  Take the difference between the two milliseconds values.

Answer (score 0):

Check [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), it has a parse function.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to you DateFormat, Date and Calendar combination as below:

```
    DateFormat dFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date1 = dFormat.parse("2012-04-23");
    Date date2 = dFormat.parse("2012-03-08");
    long timeDifInMillis = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();

    Date dateDiff = new Date(timeDifInMillis);
    Calendar diffCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    diffCal.setTime(dateDiff);
    System.out.println("Days="+diffCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    System.out.println("Months="+diffCal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    System.out.println("Years="+(diffCal.get(Calendar.YEAR)-1970));
```