# Calculating date difference between two dates in string format

Tags: java

I have two dates in string format.I need to get the difference between these two dates in days.How can I get it?I am very new to these date format.please give me any suggestion.

```
2017-06-13
2017-06-27

    String newDate = null;
    Date dtDob = new Date(GoalSelectionToDate);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    newDate = sdf.format(dtDob);

    String newDate1 = null;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    newDate1 = sdf1.format(currentDate);
    System.out.println("currentdateformat"+newDate1);
    System.out.println("anotherdateformat"+newDate);
```

Comment: Does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732577/convert-string-to-date-to-calculate-the-difference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert String to date to calculate the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732577/convert-string-to-date-to-calculate-the-difference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see below

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;

public class DatesComparison {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String date1= "2017-06-13";
        String date2= "2017-06-27";




        LocalDate localDate1 = LocalDate.parse(date1);
        LocalDate localDate2 = LocalDate.parse(date2);

        Period intervalPeriod = Period.between(localDate1, localDate2);

        System.out.println("Difference of days: " + intervalPeriod.getDays());  // Difference of days: 14
        System.out.println("Difference of months: " + intervalPeriod.getMonths());  // Difference of months: 0
        System.out.println("Difference of years: " + intervalPeriod.getYears());  // Difference of years: 0
    }
}
```

Comment: "see below" is not a helpful answer explanation.

Comment: @JoseZevallos You don't really answer the question - in particular, if the difference is more than one month, `getDays` will not return the number of days between the two dates.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8, you can parse [the dates to `LocalDate`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) without the need for a formatter because they are in ISO format:

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse("2017-06-13");
LocalDate end = LocalDate.parse("2017-06-27");
```

Then you can calculate the number of days between them with using [a `ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#DAYS):

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end);
```