# how to calculate the difference between timestamps stored as String and Datetime

Tags: java, mysql

I want to calculate the difference in minutes of two time stamp variables(`endTime_check` and `endtime`) .. first variable `endTime_check` is declared as `String` and Second variable `endtime` is taken from database type is `DateTime`.

**code is :**

```
DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String endTime_check = "";
endTime_check = timeFormat.format(cal.getTime());    
//endtime is taken from database, type is DateTime
endtime = rs.getString("endtime");
```

Comment: You want to do the calculation in Java or MySQL?

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625433/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-x-mins-x-seconds-in-java and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540801/time-difference-program/15541322#15541322 (assuming you want to calculate the difference in java)

Comment: @OP: There is no meaning in finding a time difference unless you know the dates.

Comment: [*This answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19887135/767881) should help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the duration of difference between two dates in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940200/how-to-find-the-duration-of-difference-between-two-dates-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Date endTime = rs.getDate("endtime");
String endTimeCheck = "12:34:56";

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
long endTimeCheckMillis = df.parse(endTime).getTime();
long endTimeMillis = endTime.getTime();
long differenceMinutes = Math.abs(((endTimeCheckMillis - endTimeMillis) / 60000));
```

If you want a signed difference leave out the 'Math.abs' call.