# Working with simpledateformat with milliseconds

Tags: simpledateformat

I'm parsing a file and created a custom date format using the following code:

```
        String s = tokens[0]+ " " + tokens[1];
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        try
        {
            Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(s);

           System.out.println("date : "+simpleDateFormat.format(date));

        }
        catch (ParseException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception "+ex);
        }
```

How do i work with dates from here after?

For example if i have two dates like this as per my output:

```
date : 2014-30-04 08:30:00.790

date : 2014-30-04 08:30:22.784
```

How do I calculate the time difference between them? I need minutes, seconds and milliseconds to be present in my output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate date/time difference in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351483/calculate-date-time-difference-in-java)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. A couple tips: Make the title of your question describe the key issue. Your last two sentences could have been fashioned into a better title. Also, please search StackOverflow before posting. This topic has been addressed hundreds of times.