# Time difference gives wrong value

Tags: java, date, datetime

I want to get the difference between two time values in Java. Below is the code snippet for the same:

```
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    Date date1 = sdf.parse("11:45");
    Date date2 = sdf.parse("12:00");
    System.out.println(""+(date2.getTime()-date1.getTime())/60000);

    date1 = sdf.parse("12:45");
    date2 = sdf.parse("13:00");
    System.out.println(""+(date2.getTime()-date1.getTime())/60000);

    date1 = sdf.parse("13:00");
    date2 = sdf.parse("13:15");
    System.out.println(""+(date2.getTime()-date1.getTime())/60000);
```

Output in all the three cases respectively:
Output1:-705
Output2:735
Output3:15

I don't understand why it is taking wrong value as it should be 15 in all the three cases.

Comment: If you want to get the difference of time, I'd suggest "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351483/calculate-date-time-difference-in-java ".

Comment: `hh` is 12 hour time. Try `HH:mm` instead.

Comment: You're not specifying AM or PM. `12:00` is midnight. `11:45` is nearly noon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First and biggest error:**

You use 12-hour-clock (symbol h), but symbol H would be fine.

**Another more subtle error:**

Using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is error-prone because it implicitly uses a time zone (and the result could be changed by [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) switch, see the case of [`Europe/London`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/London) when it was on Summer time in year 1970 - your implicit default year).

Therefore I suggest to use a more modern API. For example the built-in [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)) in [Java SE 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) with its [`LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) and [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) classes.

```
ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(LocalTime.parse("11:45"), LocalTime.parse("12:00"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my day.. :)

Comment: FYI… Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). Further adapted for Android in the [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.