# Find difference between two time values

Tags: java, time

There is an HTML form through which I enter the two time values, in the following manner:

[image: HTML FORM]

The data entered in HTML form is being processed by a Java Servlet. I want to find the difference between these two time values in terms of minutes in java. If I perform normal subtraction, it says **0.7**. But I want the answer to be **30 minutes**. How can I accomplish it?

Comment: You have to provide some code so that people may help you with a problem that you tried to first solve yourself. Also, this question surely has been asked dozens of times before, just look it up before asking here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate date/time difference in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351483/calculate-date-time-difference-in-java)

Comment: The same way you subtract a meter from a kilometer.  Unit conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Java8 you could use [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) like so:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import static java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.MINUTES;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalTime actualStart = LocalTime.parse("11:45"); //Change this to get the to Actual Start Time from the HTML form
    LocalTime actualStop = LocalTime.parse("12:15"); //Change this to get the to Actual Stop Time from the HTML form
    System.out.println("The difference is: " + MINUTES.between(actualStart, actualStop) + " minutes");
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
The difference is: 30 minutes
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/FgWx/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works Perfectly! :)