# Get difference in minutes between two dates java

Tags: java, jodatime

I have two dates: First one and the actual one. I need to know their difference in number of minutes. The problem is, that when using joda time:

```
 new DateTime(actual).getMinuteofDay -  new DateTime(first).getMinuteofDay
```

doesnt always return the correct answer if there is a difference in days.

Any ideas ?

Comment: This is not Android related question

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5351580/180100