# How to find scala java.util.Date difference in minutes?

Tags: scala, date, difference, date-difference, java.util.date

```
scala> val dates = filtering1.map(x => (format.parse(x._1),format.parse(x._2)))
dates: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(java.util.Date, java.util.Date)] = MapPartitionsRDD[7] at map at <console>:34
```

stores below values

```
scala> dates.collect
res0: Array[(java.util.Date, java.util.Date)] = Array((Sat Jun 30 23:42:00 IST 2018,Thu Jul 04 15:10:00 IST 2019), (Sat Jun 30 23:37:00 IST 2018,Sun Jul 01 14:44:00 IST 2018), (Sat Jun 30 23:13:00 IST 2018,Sun Feb 28 23:34:00 IST 219), (Sat Jun 30 22:58:00 IST 2018,Mon Jul 01 18:22:00 IST 2019), (Sat Jun 30 22:36:00 IST 2018,Mon Jul 01 16:01:00 IST 2019), (Sat Jun 30 21:53:00 IST 2018,Tue Jul 02 10:36:00 IST 2019), (Sat Jun 30 21:42:00 IST 2018,Sun Jun 30 23:25:00 IST 2019), (Sat Jun 30 21:36:00 IST 2018,Mon Jul 01 16:47:00 IST 2019), (Sat Jun 30 21:16:00 IST 2018,Mon Jul 01 18:18:00 IST 2019), (Sat Jun 30 21:10:00 IST 2018,Thu Jul 04 12:25:00 IST 2019), (Sat Jun 30 21:02:00 IST 2018,Sat Dec 01 17:29:00 IST 2018), (Sat Jun 30 20:54:00 IST 2018,Mon Jul 01 15:51:00 IST 2019), (Sat Jun 30 ...
```

But how to perform operation so the difference in dates, is grouped together, gives value in minutes.

I have command , it does not give me desired output, what changes should be made?

`val time_diff = dates.map(x => (x._2.getTime()-x._1.getTime())/(60*1000)%60`)

what is `(60*1000)%60)` values represent?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate date/time difference in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351483/calculate-date-time-difference-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getTime` gives milliseconds, so dividing by 1000.0 gives seconds and dividing by 1000.0*60 gives minutes. Be aware that dividing a `Long` by an `Int` gives you another `Long`, so you are truncating the resulting minutes to the next lowest integer. Adding modulus 60, `% 60`, simply wraps the minutes to 0-59, so if you had a 90 minutes difference, that would be 1 hour 30 minutes, and the result of your calculation would just be 30.

```
val t = System.currentTimeMillis
val x = new java.util.Date(t)
val y = new java.util.Date(t + 10000) // ten seconds later
(y.getTime - x.getTime) / (1000.0 * 60) // 0.167
(y.getTime - x.getTime) / (1000   * 60) // 0 !
```

Answer (score 1):

First problem when you subtract two times, time might go negative.
Second, getTime returns value in miliseconds.

```
1000ms = 1 second
```

So, first there is need to divide it by 1000 to get time in seconds. To get in minutes,divide it again by 60. 
Since you require result in minutes.

```
val time_diff = dates.map(x => (x._2.getTime()-x._1.getTime())/(60*1000))
```