# How to get the difference between two Dates in minutes in Java

Tags: java, android

I have a list of Dates that looks like this:

```
I/System.out: TAG: Mon Jun 20 15:36:00 GMT+02:00 2022
I/System.out: TAG: Mon Jun 20 15:51:55 GMT+02:00 2022
I/System.out: TAG: Mon Jun 20 15:52:14 GMT+02:00 2022
I/System.out: TAG: Mon Jun 20 16:24:01 GMT+02:00 2022
I/System.out: TAG: Mon Jun 20 18:39:07 GMT+02:00 2022
I/System.out: TAG: Mon Jun 20 18:49:02 GMT+02:00 2022
I/System.out: TAG: Mon Jun 20 20:24:26 GMT+02:00 2022
I/System.out: TAG: Mon Jun 20 20:52:23 GMT+02:00 2022
I/System.out: TAG: Mon Jun 20 22:41:50 GMT+02:00 2022
I/System.out: TAG: Mon Jun 20 22:55:54 GMT+02:00 2022
```

How do I calculate to subtract each i+1 element from the i element(example:  TAG: Mon Jun 20 15:51:55 GMT+02:00 2022 - TAG: Mon Jun 20 15:36:00 GMT+02:00 2022) difference is 21 minutes.

I tryed something like this:

```
 for(int i=0;i<list.size()-1;i++){
                     parked += list.get(i+1).getTime() - list.get(i).getTime();
                    }
System.out.println("parked time:  "+parked / 60 000);
```

and I get 434 minutes instead of 98...
Can someone help?
Thanks in regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate date/time difference in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351483/calculate-date-time-difference-in-java)

Comment: What kind of objects do you store in your list? What is the return type of `getTime()` ?

Comment: In my list there is a list of dates as above

Comment: In my list I insert Date objects, long in milliseconds @Eritrean

Comment: it is strongly advised to NOT use `java.util.Date` anymore; use classes from the `java.time` package! Anyway, you can do `Duration.between(d1.toInstant(), d2.toInstant()).toMinutes()` to get the difference between Dates `d1` and `d2`

Comment: Use `OffsetDateTime` (or `ZonedDateTime`) and `ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between()`.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your question i found this other post that is able to solve your issue. The code presented as solution is able to convert Date to simple readable values.

[Calculating the difference between two Java date instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

```
/**
 * Get a diff between two dates
 * @param date1 the oldest date
 * @param date2 the newest date
 * @param timeUnit the unit in which you want the diff
 * @return the diff value, in the provided unit
 */
public static long getDateDiff(Date date1, Date date2, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
    long diffInMillies = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    return timeUnit.convert(diffInMillies,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Then you need to call to obtain your value

```
getDateDiff(date1,date2,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
public double  findDifference(String start_date, String end_date)
{
    // SimpleDateFormat converts the
    // string format to date object
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
   double diff = 0;
    // Try Block
    try {
        // parse method is used to parse
        // the text from a string to
        // produce the date
        Date d1 = sdf.parse(start_date);
        Date d2 = sdf.parse(end_date);
        // Calucalte time difference
        // in milliseconds
        long difference_In_Time = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

        // Calucalte time difference in
        // seconds, minutes, hours, years,
        // and days
        long difference_In_Seconds = (difference_In_Time / 1000) % 60;

        long difference_In_Minutes = (difference_In_Time / (1000 * 60)) % 60;

        long day   = (difference_In_Time / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;

        long difference_In_Years = (difference_In_Time / (1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365));

        long difference_In_Days = (difference_In_Time / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) % 365;

        // Print the date difference in
        // years, in days, in hours, in
        // minutes, and in seconds
    }

    // Catch the Exception
    catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return diff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll make sure not to make this mistake next time