# JTextField time in HH:mm:ss

Tags: java, swing, time, formatting, jformattedtextfield

I have the estimated time the it would take for a particular task in minutes in a float. How can I put this in a JFormattedTextField in the format of `HH:mm:ss`?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you read the tutorial?  http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html#format

Comment: This sounds like a task better suited to a `JProgressBar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JFormattedTextField` accepts a `Format` object - you could thus pass a `DateFormat` that you get by calling [`DateFormat#getTimeInstance()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getTimeInstance%28%29). You might also use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with `HH:mm:ss` as the format string.

See also:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html#format

---

If you're not restricted to using a `JFormattedTextField`, you might also consider doing your own formatting using the [`TimeUnit`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) class, available since Java 1.5, as shown in this answer: [How to convert Milliseconds to "X mins, x seconds" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625433/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-x-mins-x-seconds-in-java/625624#625624)

Comment: @dah Do you have a base `Date` that you can work with i.e. do you have the time *from* which it's going to take, say, 5 minutes, to do finish the task?

Comment: Nope. it's only recorded in decimal minutes.

Comment: I think I'm just going to just convert minutes to seconds to millis then use that in a date constructor and use your method.

Comment: @dah I don't think that will work, you will still need a base `Date` object to work with - just milliseconds from a value like 5 minutes will only give you a time relative to the start of the epoch (January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT). See my edited answer for how you might format it the way you want, quite easily, with the `TimeUnit` class.

Comment: Isn't 5 minutes from the epoch the same as five minutes from x.

Comment: @dah, yes. But it may not get you the result you expect. Try this code: `System.out.println(new Date(0)); System.out.println(new Date(5 * 60 * 1000));`
One option that might be good for you is using `TimeUnit` and the pointed article to implement your own Format class (just extend java.text.Format and implement the abstract methods). This way you get the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 6):

For a float < 1440 you can get around with `Calendar` and `DateFormat`.

```
float minutes = 100.5f; // 1:40:30

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, (int) minutes);
c.add(Calendar.SECOND, (int) ((minutes % (int) minutes) * 60));
final Date date = c.getTime();

Format timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
JFormattedTextField input = new JFormattedTextField(timeFormat);
input.setValue(date);
```

But be warned that if your float is greater than or equal to 1440 (24 hours) the Calendar method will just forward a day and you will not get the expected results.