# Convert seconds value to hours minutes seconds?

Tags: java, android, string, android-edittext, bigdecimal

I've been trying to convert a value of seconds (in a BigDecimal variable) to a string in an editText like "1 hour 22 minutes 33 seconds" or something of the kind.

I've tried this:

```
String sequenceCaptureTime = "";
BigDecimal roundThreeCalc = new BigDecimal("0");
BigDecimal hours = new BigDecimal("0");
BigDecimal myremainder = new BigDecimal("0");
BigDecimal minutes = new BigDecimal("0");
BigDecimal seconds = new BigDecimal("0");
BigDecimal var3600 = new BigDecimal("3600");
BigDecimal var60 = new BigDecimal("60");
```

(I have a roundThreeCalc which is the value in seconds so I try to convert it here.)

```
hours = (roundThreeCalc.divide(var3600));
myremainder = (roundThreeCalc.remainder(var3600));
minutes = (myremainder.divide(var60));
seconds = (myremainder.remainder(var60));
sequenceCaptureTime =  hours.toString() + minutes.toString() + seconds.toString();
```

Then I set the editText to sequnceCaptureTime String.
But that didn't work. It force closed the app every time. I am totally out of my depth here, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert Milliseconds to "X mins, x seconds" in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625433/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-x-mins-x-seconds-in-java)

Comment: Any reason why you are using BigDecimal instead of BigInteger?

Comment: I will have to implement fractions of a second later on in dev, right now I am just trying to get the calculation to work in the first place.

Comment: I second Richard's comment - you can use the TimeUnit enum to do a lot of the work for you. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html

Comment: How would I go about using timeunit to convert from a BigDecimal with seconds in it to HHMMSS?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You should have more luck with

```
hours = roundThreeCalc.divide(var3600, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
myremainder = roundThreeCalc.remainder(var3600);
minutes = myremainder.divide(var60, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
seconds = myremainder.remainder(var60);
```

This will drop the decimal values after each division.

Edit: If that didn't work, try this.  (I just wrote and tested it)

```
public static int[] splitToComponentTimes(BigDecimal biggy)
{
    long longVal = biggy.longValue();
    int hours = (int) longVal / 3600;
    int remainder = (int) longVal - hours * 3600;
    int mins = remainder / 60;
    remainder = remainder - mins * 60;
    int secs = remainder;

    int[] ints = {hours , mins , secs};
    return ints;
}
```

Comment: This solution is more graceful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625433/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-x-mins-x-seconds-in-java

Comment: @AlexKucherenko except that solution works with milliseconds

Comment: @Mikhail TimeUnit.#### will allow you to do it with any unit of time.

Comment: Whenever you find yourself doing math with time and date values, you need to stop yourself and find the right API in the language at hand. If you just need a HH:MM:SS-type response, you'll be better off with `DateUtils.formatElapsedTime`...

Answer (score 304):

Is it necessary to use a BigDecimal? If you don't have to, I'd use an int or long for seconds, and it would simplify things a little bit:

```
hours = totalSecs / 3600;
minutes = (totalSecs % 3600) / 60;
seconds = totalSecs % 60;

timeString = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
```

You might want to pad each to make sure they're two digit values(or whatever) in the string, though.

Comment: I will have to implement fractions of a second later on in dev, right now I am just trying to get the calculation to work in the first place.

Comment: `String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);`

Comment: This is simply impressive. I wonder how modulus could work in this way.

Comment: Use Locale otherwise it will gives you warning. `String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)`

Comment: Whenever you find yourself doing math with time and date values, you need to stop yourself and find the right API in the language at hand. If you just need a HH:MM:SS-type response, you'll be better off with `DateUtils.formatElapsedTime`...

Comment: @dovetalk That can definitely be useful, and was added as a separate answer [several years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33105053/752320).

Comment: @Geobits, yes, and thanks for linking to it. I spammed many of the "solutions" here with that comment to raise awareness to less experienced developers that are likely to be tempted to roll-their-own. There are some domains where that is generally a bad idea. Time arithmetic is one

Comment: @dovetalk In general yes, but seconds/minutes are mostly safer than days/years by a long shot. As usual, a lot of ways to do a simple thing.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer as it is cleaner and the hours calculation will show the actual total hours instead of a % mod value of hours.

Answer (score 109):

`DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(long)`, formats an elapsed time in the form "`MM:SS`" or "`H:MM:SS`" . It returns the String you are looking for. You can find the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#formatElapsedTime(long))

Comment: This one is simple and exactly what I need. I recommend others this method

Comment: Don't forget that it expect parameter in seconds. So you need to convert millis to seconds

Comment: Please specify the package of DateUtils. There are hundreds of DateUtils in diffrent libs! ```android.text.format.DateUtils.formatElapsedTime```

Comment: @Nano it is in the documentation I liked to the answer

Answer (score 36):

### Something really helpful in Java 8

```
import java.time.LocalTime;

private String ConvertSecondToHHMMSSString(int nSecondTime) {
    return LocalTime.MIN.plusSeconds(nSecondTime).toString();
}
```

Comment: **Note:** The calculation wraps around midnight when using plusSeconds(long seconds), **for eg:** if seconds is 86400(24 hrs) it outputs 00:00.

Comment: It does exactly what the name suggests 'ConvertSecondToHHMMSSString'. The other (tedious) solutions are also wrapping around.

Comment: @Epicurist this was the solution I was looking for! Much more elegant and than all the others! :)

Comment: Wouldn't work when hour count exceeds 24

Answer (score 30):

Here is the working code:

```
private String getDurationString(int seconds) {

    int hours = seconds / 3600;
    int minutes = (seconds % 3600) / 60;
    seconds = seconds % 60;

    return twoDigitString(hours) + " : " + twoDigitString(minutes) + " : " + twoDigitString(seconds);
}

private String twoDigitString(int number) {

    if (number == 0) {
        return "00";
    }

    if (number / 10 == 0) {
        return "0" + number;
    }

    return String.valueOf(number);
}
```

Comment: I like this answer but you need to change '% 10' to '/ 10'

Comment: Whenever you find yourself doing math with time and date values, you need to stop yourself and find the right API in the language at hand. If you just need a HH:MM:SS-type response, you'll be better off with `DateUtils.formatElapsedTime`...

Answer (score 26):

I prefer java's built in **TimeUnit** library

```
long seconds = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(8);
```

Comment: How is that supposed to convert seconds to hours, minutes?

Answer (score 14):

```
private String ConvertSecondToHHMMString(int secondtTime)
{
  TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
  SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
  df.setTimeZone(tz);
  String time = df.format(new Date(secondtTime*1000L));

  return time;

}
```

Comment: You could further improve your answer by explaining what the code does and how it solves the problem ;-)

Comment: The provided code won't work as I would expect if you have more seconds than 24 hours.

Answer (score 11):

If you want the units `h`, `min` and `sec` for a duration you can use this:

```
public static String convertSeconds(int seconds) {
    int h = seconds/ 3600;
    int m = (seconds % 3600) / 60;
    int s = seconds % 60;
    String sh = (h > 0 ? String.valueOf(h) + " " + "h" : "");
    String sm = (m < 10 && m > 0 && h > 0 ? "0" : "") + (m > 0 ? (h > 0 && s == 0 ? String.valueOf(m) : String.valueOf(m) + " " + "min") : "");
    String ss = (s == 0 && (h > 0 || m > 0) ? "" : (s < 10 && (h > 0 || m > 0) ? "0" : "") + String.valueOf(s) + " " + "sec");
    return sh + (h > 0 ? " " : "") + sm + (m > 0 ? " " : "") + ss;
}

int seconds = 3661;
String duration = convertSeconds(seconds);
```

That's a lot of conditional operators. The method will return those strings:

```
0    -> 0 sec
5    -> 5 sec
60   -> 1 min
65   -> 1 min 05 sec
3600 -> 1 h
3601 -> 1 h 01 sec
3660 -> 1 h 01
3661 -> 1 h 01 min 01 sec
108000 -> 30 h
```

Answer (score 11):

This is my simple solution:

```
String secToTime(int sec) {
    int seconds = sec % 60;
    int minutes = sec / 60;
    if (minutes >= 60) {
        int hours = minutes / 60;
        minutes %= 60;
        if( hours >= 24) {
            int days = hours / 24;
            return String.format("%d days %02d:%02d:%02d", days,hours%24, minutes, seconds);
        }
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
    }
    return String.format("00:%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
}
```

[`Test Results`](https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/seconds_to_hh_mm_ss/):

```
Result: 00:00:36 - 36
Result: 01:00:07 - 3607
Result: 6313 days 12:39:05 - 545488745
```

Answer (score 7):

### Duration from java.time

```
    BigDecimal secondsValue = BigDecimal.valueOf(4953);
    if (secondsValue.compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE)) > 0) {
        System.out.println("Seconds value " + secondsValue + " is out of range");
    } else {
        Duration dur = Duration.ofSeconds(secondsValue.longValueExact());
        long hours = dur.toHours();
        int minutes = dur.toMinutesPart();
        int seconds = dur.toSecondsPart();

        System.out.format("%d hours %d minutes %d seconds%n", hours, minutes, seconds);
    }
```

Output from this snippet is:

> 1 hours 22 minutes 33 seconds

If there had been a non-zero fraction of second in the `BigDecimal` this code would not have worked as it stands, but you may be able to modify it. The code works in Java 9 and later. In Java 8 the conversion from `Duration` into hours minutes and seconds is a bit more wordy, see the link at the bottom for how. I am leaving to you to choose the correct singular or plural form of the words (*hour* or *hours*, etc.).

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Answer by lauhub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51091602/5772882) showing the conversion from a `Duration` to days, hours, minutes and seconds in Java 8.

Answer (score 5):

I like to keep things simple therefore:

```
    int tot_seconds = 5000;
    int hours = tot_seconds / 3600;
    int minutes = (tot_seconds % 3600) / 60;
    int seconds = tot_seconds % 60;

    String timeString = String.format("%02d Hour %02d Minutes %02d Seconds ", hours, minutes, seconds);

    System.out.println(timeString);
```

The result will be: 01 Hour 23 Minutes 20 Seconds

Comment: shortest Answer , Awesome

Answer (score 5):

This Code Is working Fine :

```
txtTimer.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",(SecondsCounter/3600), ((SecondsCounter % 3600)/60), (SecondsCounter % 60)));
```

Answer (score 4):

A nice and easy way to do it using GregorianCalendar

Import these into the project:

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

And then:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Seconds: ");
int secs = s.nextInt();

GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(0,0,0,0,0,secs);
Date dNow = cal.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("HH 'hours' mm 'minutes' ss 'seconds'");
System.out.println("Your time: " + ft.format(dNow));
```

Answer (score 4):

for just minutes and seconds use this

```
String.format("%02d:%02d", (seconds / 3600 * 60 + ((seconds % 3600) / 60)), (seconds % 60))
```

Answer (score 4):

With Java 8, you can easily achieve time in String format from long seconds like,

```
LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(86399L)
```

Here, given value is max allowed to convert (upto 24 hours) and result will be

```
23:59:59
```

Pros : 1) No need to convert manually and to append 0 for single digit

Cons : work only for up to 24 hours

Answer (score 2):

Here's my function to address the problem:

```
public static String getConvertedTime(double time){

    double h,m,s,mil;

    mil = time % 1000;
    s = time/1000;
    m = s/60;
    h = m/60;
    s = s % 60;
    m = m % 60;
    h = h % 24;

    return ((int)h < 10 ? "0"+String.valueOf((int)h) : String.valueOf((int)h))+":"+((int)m < 10 ? "0"+String.valueOf((int)m) : String.valueOf((int)m))
            +":"+((int)s < 10 ? "0"+String.valueOf((int)s) : String.valueOf((int)s))
            +":"+((int)mil > 100 ? String.valueOf((int)mil) : (int)mil > 9 ? "0"+String.valueOf((int)mil) : "00"+String.valueOf((int)mil));
}
```

Comment: Why this infant way using Double typed variables to store the necessary ints?

Answer (score 2):

I use this:

```
 public String SEG2HOR( long lnValue) {     //OK
        String lcStr = "00:00:00";
        String lcSign = (lnValue>=0 ? " " : "-");
        lnValue = lnValue * (lnValue>=0 ? 1 : -1); 

        if (lnValue>0) {                
            long lnHor  = (lnValue/3600);
            long lnHor1 = (lnValue % 3600);
            long lnMin  = (lnHor1/60);
            long lnSec  = (lnHor1 % 60);            

                        lcStr = lcSign + ( lnHor < 10 ? "0": "") + String.valueOf(lnHor) +":"+
                              ( lnMin < 10 ? "0": "") + String.valueOf(lnMin) +":"+
                              ( lnSec < 10 ? "0": "") + String.valueOf(lnSec) ;
        }

        return lcStr;           
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is pretty old but in java 8:

```
LocalTime.MIN.plusSeconds(120).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this in python to convert a float representing seconds to hours, minutes, seconds, and microseconds. It's reasonably elegant and is handy for converting to a datetime type via strptime to convert.  It could also be easily extended to longer intervals (weeks, months, etc.) if needed.

```
    def sectohmsus(seconds):
        x = seconds
        hmsus = []
        for i in [3600, 60, 1]:  # seconds in a hour, minute, and second
            hmsus.append(int(x / i))
            x %= i
        hmsus.append(int(round(x * 1000000)))  # microseconds
        return hmsus  # hours, minutes, seconds, microsecond
```

Answer (score 1):

i have tried the best way and less code but may be it is little bit difficult to understand how i wrote my code but if you good at maths it is so easy

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

class hours {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double s;


    System.out.println("how many second you have ");
    s =input.nextInt();



     double h=s/3600;
     int h2=(int)h;

     double h_h2=h-h2;
     double m=h_h2*60;
     int m1=(int)m;

     double m_m1=m-m1;
     double m_m1s=m_m1*60;






     System.out.println(h2+" hours:"+m1+" Minutes:"+Math.round(m_m1s)+" seconds");





}
```

}

more over it is accurate !

Answer (score 1):

You can get this done easily using method overloading.

Here's a code I wrote to convert seconds to hours, minutes and seconds format.

```
public class SecondsAndMinutes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String finalOutput = getDurationString(-3666);

        System.out.println(finalOutput);

    }

    public static String getDurationString(int seconds) {
         if(seconds <= 0) {
             return "Add a value bigger than zero.";
         }else {

             int hours = seconds / (60*60);
             int remainingOneSeconds = seconds % (60*60);
             int minutes = remainingOneSeconds / 60;
             int remainingSeconds = remainingOneSeconds % 60;

             String x = Integer.toString(hours);

             return x+"h " + getDurationString(minutes, remainingSeconds);
         }
    }

    public static String getDurationString(int minutes, int seconds) {
        if(seconds <= 0 && seconds > 59) {
            return "Seconds needs to be within 1 to 59";
        }else {

            String y = Integer.toString(minutes);
            String z = Integer.toString(seconds);

            return y+"m "+z+"s";
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tough there are yet many correct answers and an accepted one, if you want a more handmade and systematized way to do this, I suggest something like this:

```java
/**
 * Factors for converting seconds in minutes, minutes in hours, etc.
 */
private static int[] FACTORS = new int[] {
    60, 60, 24, 7
};

/**
 * Names of each time unit.
 * The length of this array needs to be FACTORS.length + 1.
 * The last one is the name of the remainder after
 * obtaining each component.
 */
private static String[] NAMES = new String[] {
    "second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week"
};

/**
 * Checks if quantity is 1 in order to use or not the plural.
 */
private static String quantityToString(int quantity, String name) {
    if (quantity == 1) {
        return String.format("%d %s", quantity, name);
    }
    return String.format("%d %ss", quantity, name);
}

/**
 * The seconds to String method.
 */
private static String secondsToString(int seconds) {
    List<String> components = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Obtains each component and stores only if is not 0.
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < FACTORS.length; i++) {
        int component = seconds % FACTORS[i];
        seconds /= FACTORS[i];
        if (component != 0) {
            components.add(quantityToString(component, NAMES[i]));
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * The remainder is the last component.
     */
    if (seconds != 0) {
        components.add(quantityToString(seconds, NAMES[FACTORS.length]));
    }
    
    /**
     * We have the non-0 components in reversed order.
     * This could be extracted to another method.
     */
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = components.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i == 0 && components.size() > 1) {
            builder.append(" and ");
        } else if (builder.length() > 0) {
            builder.append(", ");
        }
        builder.append(components.get(i));
    }
    
    return builder.toString();
}
```

The result is as following:

```java
System.out.println(secondsToString(5_000_000)); // 8 weeks, 1 day, 20 hours, 53 minutes and 20 seconds
System.out.println(secondsToString(500_000)); // 5 days, 18 hours, 53 minutes and 20 seconds
System.out.println(secondsToString(60*60*24)); // 1 day
System.out.println(secondsToString(2*60*60*24 + 3*60)); // 2 days and 3 minutes
System.out.println(secondsToString(60*60*24 + 3 * 60 * 60 + 53)); // 1 day, 3 hours and 53 seconds
```