# How can I get seconds and milliseconds together from time?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, parseint

I am trying to get page load time in automation testing project.

```
pageLoad3.start();
        WebDriverWait wait3 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait3.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(hotelNameDetailsXpath)));
        pageLoad3.stop();
        long pageLoadTime_ms5 = pageLoad3.getTime();
        long pageLoadTime_Seconds5 = pageLoadTime_ms5 / 1000;
        //System.out.println("Time taken to get load Total price element ::");
        System.out.println("pageLoadTime_ms5 ::"+pageLoadTime_ms5);
        System.out.println("Time taken to load DB Response :: " + pageLoadTime_Seconds5 + " seconds");
```

Output:

```
pageLoadTime_ms5 ::11479
Time taken to load DB Response ::  11 seconds
```

I am getting **11** seconds but not able to get for **479**, how can I get it in below format?

- Actual Requirement: I want time to get in below format like

  ```
  11 seconds 47 milliseconds i.e. (00:11:47)
  ```

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118922/convert-seconds-value-to-hours-minutes-seconds

Comment: Please check it once. Please refer output and actual requirement. Its not about HH:MM:SS.

Comment: Once you have time in ms, it is easy to find other components like hour, minute, second, ms using divide and modulo.
ms/1000 = second, ms%1000 = ms_component and so on.

Answer (score 0):

To get the output as **11 seconds 47 milliseconds** you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  public class division_by_1000 {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          //long pageLoadTime_ms5 = pageLoad3.getTime();
          // assuming pageLoadTime_ms5 = 11479
          String pageLoadTime_ms5 = "11479";
          System.out.println("pageLoadTime_ms5 ::"+pageLoadTime_ms5);
          System.out.println("Time taken to load DB Response :: " + (Integer.parseInt(pageLoadTime_ms5)/1000) + " seconds " + (Integer.parseInt(pageLoadTime_ms5)%1000) + " millisseconds ");
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  pageLoadTime_ms5 ::11479
  Time taken to load DB Response :: 11 seconds 479 millisseconds
  ```