# Can someone explain on how to convert huge number of seconds when getting to readable minutes and seconds?

Tags: java, time

I'm working on a code converting huge numbers, such as 9999 to 2:46:39 into this format HH:MM:SS. I do understand how to get 2 hour and kind of on 46 minutes, but not so much with 39 seconds. Can anyone please this explain this to me? When I tried a different number like 4555 seconds I get 1:15:55. I understand the hour part, but now I don't on 15 minutes and 55 seconds. I think only minutes and seconds are the only things that I'm not sure of.

I'm using % to get the remainder, but when I divide them 60, especially for 4555 I don't see any 15 or 55 seconds as a remainder when using normal division.

`int min = ttlNumSec % MIN60; 
 int sec = ttlNumSec % MIN60;`

Appreciate any help.

Edit: Thank you so much to all who replied and showing another ways of getting them :D

Comment: `9999 % 60 = 39`, `9999 / 60 = 166`, `166 % 60 = 46`, `166 / 60 = 2`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert seconds value to hours minutes seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118922/convert-seconds-value-to-hours-minutes-seconds) Please search for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a number of seconds `ttlNumSec`, you can get how many hours it is by:

```
ttlNumSec / 3600
```

`3600` is the number of seconds in an hour.

You can get the number of minutes by:

```
ttlNumSec % 3600 / 60
```

`60` is the number of seconds in a minute. Why do `ttlNumSec % 3600` first? Because that is equal to the number of seconds that is not enough to form another whole hour, and you want to get how many minutes that is.

To get the seconds, do:

```
ttlNumSec % 60
```

Java 9's `Duration` class actually has all these calculations built in, so you don't need to calculate them:

```
Duration d = Duration.ofSeconds(ttlNumSec);
int hours = d.toHours();
int minutes = d.toMinutesPart();
int seconds = d.toSecondsPart();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long time = 1536259;

return (new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss:SSS")).format(new Date(time))
```

Output:

> 25:36:259

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Also your code will give incorrect results on most JVMs.

Comment: Also in some time zones it will give incorrect results. When one day you run your code on a computer in Nepal or India and it suddenly gives an incorrect result, you may have a very hard time to find out why. Furthermore it doesn’t detect overflow (more than 60 minutes) but just tacitly throws away the hours.