# Is there a way to do 24-hour format and 60-minute format in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, time

```java
if(ExcessTimeHours >= 24) {
    ExcessTimeHours = 0;
}
if(ExcessTimeMin >= 60) {
    ExcessTimeMin = 0;
    ExcessTimeHours ++;
}
```

I add time when the first movie starts, then I add how long is that movie and then I add when the second movie starts, also add how long this movie is and the program will tell me if I am able to see both movies with no problem, or if I will miss some minutes of the movie or if I am not able to make it.

My problem is that I don't know how to fix that when the time reaches over midnight and jumps from 24 to 0 hours. Can't figure out the condition.

```
    System.out.println("Start of movie A:");
    
    System.out.print("hour: ");                         // 17; 23; 0
    int startHourA = s.nextInt();
    System.out.print("min: ");                          // 30; 30; 30
    int startMinA = s.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("Length of movie A:");
    
    System.out.print("hour: ");                         // 2; 2; 2
    int lengthHourA = s.nextInt();
    System.out.print("min: ");                          // 0; 0; 1
    int lengthMinA = s.nextInt();
    
    
    System.out.println("Start of movie B:");
    
    System.out.print("hour: ");                         // 20; 0; 0
    int startHourB = s.nextInt();
    System.out.print("min: ");                          // 0; 20; 31
    int startMinB = s.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("Length of movie B:");
    
    System.out.print("hour: ");                         // 0; 1; 2
    int lengthHourB = s.nextInt();
    System.out.print("min: ");                          // 35; 35; 0
    int lengthMinB = s.nextInt();


    int timeBetweenMoviesHour = startHourB - ExcessTimeHours;
    int timeBetweenMoviesMin = startMinB - ExcessTimeMin;

    if (timeBetweenMoviesHour == 0 && timeBetweenMoviesMin >= 0) {
        System.out.println("Recommendation: No problem");
    }
    else if (timeBetweenMoviesMin > 0) {
        System.out.println("Recommendation: You won't see " + 
        timeBetweenMoviesMin + " minutes");
    }
    else System.out.println("Recommendation: You can't make it");
```

Comment: Please add more detail to your question, as it is currently unclear. What are you trying to do? What should happen? What is currently not working?

Comment: Why are you setting the values to `0` when they exceed `24` or `60`? That means if you had `ExcessTimeMin == 493`, with your code that would equal to `ExcessTimeHours == 1` and `ExcessTimeMin == 0`, which is wrong. If anything, you need to substract multiples of `24` or `60` from your fields until you fit into the valid range again.

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly what I don't know how to do. I know this is wrong written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### java.time

You will want to use the `LocalTime` and `Duration` classes. For example like the following. I don’t think my code does exactly what you want your code to do, but it should get you started.

```
    // Convert inputs to LocalTime and Duration objects

    LocalTime startMovieA = LocalTime.of(16, 0);
    Duration lengthMoviaA = Duration.ofHours(2).plusMinutes(15);

    LocalTime startMovieB = LocalTime.of(18, 45);

    // Do calculations

    LocalTime endMovieA = startMovieA.plus(lengthMoviaA);
    Duration timeBetweenMovies = Duration.between(endMovieA, startMovieB);

    // Output

    if (timeBetweenMovies.isNegative()) {
        System.out.println("You will be missing " + timeBetweenMovies.abs());
    }
    else if (timeBetweenMovies.isZero()) {
        System.out.println("You will just make it");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("You will have " + timeBetweenMovies + " between the movies");
    }
```

Output is:

> You will have PT30M between the movies

`Duration` objects print a little funny. The format is ISO 8601. For your user you will want to format more nicely, like `You will have 30 minutes between the movies`. Search for how and/or use the links at the bottom. It’s described in various places on the WWW.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- Questions and answers on how to format a `Duration`:

  - [Convert seconds value to hours minutes seconds? — My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59568939/5772882)
  - [How to format a duration in java? (e.g format H:MM:SS) — Answer by lauhub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51091602/5772882)

Comment: Oh yeah, I found it. Sorry for confusion, I'm kinda new here.

Comment: Yeah, it takes a bit to learn how it all works here. We’ve all been there.