# Format error of time difference

Tags: android, calendar, date-formatting

I want to calc the time differnce from when the user pressed start and stop. 
This is what I got so far:

Done in not worker thread:

```
runTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Done on main thread:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss.SSS");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() - runTime);
timeTextView.setText("Time: " + formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

The result is always "01:00:00.000". 
How come I get a 1hour added to the time?
And ofc I press the start and stop button faster then one hour.

Comment: did you try setting the time zone? for example `calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));` ?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540380/format-milliseconds-to-simpledate-format)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of solving (working around ?) this issue:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

//* do something

long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

long elapsedTimeInMilliSecs=(endTime - startTime);

Calendar ...
```

I use something like this and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The result you have is the time since [epoch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263148/how-to-find-seconds-since-1970-in-java) in java, So if you try to print

`timeTextView.setText("Time: " + calendar.getTime().toString());`

You are more likely to have the result of `Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969` depends on which `TimeZone` you currently are. From your code above I got `07:00:00:000` because I am at EST TimeZone. You cant really do about it but it eliminate the `hh` so it will only show the minutes, seconds, and milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you just want your elapsed time in HH:MM:SS, this works even if you have more than 24 hours.

```
timeTextView.setText("Time: " + convertMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() - runTime));
...
public static String convertMillis(long milliseconds){  
    long time = milliseconds / 1000;  
    String seconds = Integer.toString((int)(time % 60));  
    String minutes = Integer.toString((int)((time % 3600) / 60));  
    String hours = Integer.toString((int)(time / 3600));  
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {  
        if (seconds.length() < 2) {  
            seconds = "0" + seconds;  
        }  
        if (minutes.length() < 2) {  
            minutes = "0" + minutes;  
        }  
        if (hours.length() < 2) {  
            hours = "0" + hours;  
         }  
    }  
    return(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);  
}
```