# Java determine if a time is X minutes greater

Tags: java, parsing, date, simpledateformat, milliseconds

I know how to determine IF a time stamp is "greater than" "equal to" or "less than" using the date function, but I don't know how to determine HOW MUCH greater than a time is

for instance, how would I tell that 6:15 PM is 15 minutes greater than 6:00 PM

I've got an idea to convert times into milliseconds and compare with the current time in milliseconds, but its a fog of potential ideas right now

insight appreciated

Comment: Why don't you try your ideas first?

Comment: I'd like to know of more efficient ways to tackle this problem before/while I reinvent the wheel

Comment: @fireshadow52 don't forget dividing to get it into minutes :-P

Comment: @RD. Show us some code to see what you are thinking, maybe you are not reinventing the wheel but using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see [how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-x-mins-x-seconds-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625433/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-x-mins-x-seconds-in-java)

Then you can do something like this...

```
final Date a = someDate();
final Date b = anotherDate();
final long millis = b.getTime() - a.getTime();

int minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis);
```

Also,  take a look at [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) at some point.  It's pretty much the de-facto standard for better date and time functions in java.  They have some nice convenience methods like `Minutes.minutesBetween(date1,date2)`

Answer (score -1):

Just create two date stamps you want and convert into milliseconds and subract them and return the difference.

```
Date date1 = System.currentMilliSeconds();
Date date2 = System.currentMilliSeconds();
return new Date(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());
```