# How to extract the portion of a video corresponding to a given audio clip?

Tags: java, audio, video, ffmpeg, audio-fingerprinting

I have a video clip, and an audio clip extracted from it.
How can I trim the the video clip to to the portion extracted in the audio clip?

I imagine the solution will consist of:

1. *Automatically* identify the pair of start position of the audio clip in the video clip, and the end position (e.g. <03:05,09:55>);
2. Trim the video from the identified start to the identified end (that's easy).

Answer (score 0):

To trim your video you can use ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 30 -t 90 -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.mp4
```

With -ss you mark your start and with -t the final duration. The -t option indicates the diference between your two absolute positions, you have to calculate it, [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625433/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-x-mins-x-seconds-in-java/625624#625624) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266825/how-to-format-a-duration-in-java-e-g-format-hmmss/266970#266970)