# How to convert milliseconds to "hh:mm:ss" format?

Tags: java, time-format, countdowntimer

I'm confused. After stumbling upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625433/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-x-mins-x-seconds-in-java) thread, I tried to figure out how to format a countdown timer that had the format `hh:mm:ss`.

Here's my attempt -

```
//hh:mm:ss
String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", 
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - 
    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - 
    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
```

So, when I try a value like `3600000ms`, I get `01:59:00`, which is wrong since it should be `01:00:00`. Obviously there's something wrong with my logic, but at the moment, I cannot see what it is!

Can anyone help?

**Edit -**

Fixed it. Here's the right way to format milliseconds to `hh:mm:ss` format -

```
//hh:mm:ss
String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", 
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - 
    TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - 
    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))));
```

The problem was this `TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis))`. It should have been this `TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis))` instead.

Comment: 3,600,000 milliseconds is 3,600 seconds, or 60 minutes, or 1 hour. It shouldn't be `00:59:59`, it should be `01:00:00`.

Answer (score 420, accepted):

You were *really* close:

```
String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", 
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) -  
TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)), // The change is in this line
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - 
TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
```

You were converting hours to millisseconds using *minutes* instead of *hours*.

BTW, I like your use of the `TimeUnit` API :)

Here's some test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    long millis = 3600000;
    String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
    System.out.println(hms);
}
```

Output:

```
01:00:00
```

---

I realised that my code above can be greatly simplified by using a modulus division instead of subtraction:

```
String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) % TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) % TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1));
```

Still using the `TimeUnit` API for all magic values, and gives exactly the same output.

Comment: It is not a good idea to reinvent the wheel! Triton Man's answer is better solution.

Comment: @محمدباقر But the other answer uses an external library, whereas my code uses the core JDK only. It depends on what your needs are - for example you may not be able to use an external library. The other answer is good though.

Comment: How 'bout when it exceeds 365 days? Can you do the equivalent years? Thanks.

Comment: @KarenAnne what do you mean? Can you give sample input and output please?

Comment: @محمدباقر I needed to add Days and extra text to the string. in this answer, easily i inserted my text between the %02d and finished, what about doing this with the answer you suggested is better than this ?

Comment: Given time in milliseconds, say the time is not upto an hour, it returns for example "00:15:23". Is there any way to make it remove zeros if empty? For example to return "15:23" instead of "00:15:23".

Comment: @Ozuf add `.replaceAll("^00:", "")` or `.replaceAll("^00:(00:)?", "")` to remove minutes as well as hours if both are zero.

Comment: Thanks but what happens if the time is "00:15:00" or "10:00:23"?

Comment: @Ozuf you get `"15:00"` and `"10:00:23"` respectively; only *leading* zeros are removed, due to the match being anchored to start of input by `^`.

Comment: Thanks a million :D. Please can you update the answer so that others can easily see it?

Comment: int hrs = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(miliSeconds) % 24;
  int min = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(miliSeconds) % 60;
  int sec = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(miliSeconds) % 60;
  return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hrs, min, sec);

Answer (score 98):

The generic method for this is fairly simple:

```
public static String convertSecondsToHMmSs(long seconds) {
    long s = seconds % 60;
    long m = (seconds / 60) % 60;
    long h = (seconds / (60 * 60)) % 24;
    return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", h,m,s);
}
```

Comment: @Javaman59, did you mean `String.format("%` **02** `d:%02d:%02d", h,m,s)`?

Comment: @KarenAnne. That depends on whether you want, for example, "03:59:59" or "3:59:59".

Comment: The time's in milliseconds, you need to multiply seconds with 1000

Comment: author asked about milliseconds, not seconds!

Answer (score 71):

If you are using apache commons:

```
DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(timeInMS, "HH:mm:ss,SSS");
```

Comment: Shortcut : `DurationFormatUtils.formatDurationHMS(timeInMS);`

Comment: @Jorgesys Why are they obsolete?

Comment: they aren't obsolete.

Answer (score 31):

I used this:

```
String.format("%1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS.%1$tL", millis);
```

See description of class [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

See [runnable example](https://repl.it/repls/MildTediousTrees) using input of 2400 ms.

Comment: It seems not working, I simply test it by pass 100, 1000, 1200 and it responding as _05:30:00_ , _05:30:01_, _05:30:01_.

Comment: @CoDe, it works for your time zone.  You must be in a different time zone than UTC.  `String.format()` is time zone _dependent_.  The ideal correct answer, however, should be time zone _independent_.

Comment: @CoDe, it is showing times that correspond to your time zone which must be different than UTC. `String.format()` is time zone _dependent_. The ideal correct answer, however, should be time zone _independent_.

Answer (score 30):

```
// New date object from millis
Date date = new Date(millis);
// formattter 
SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
// Pass date object
String formatted = formatter.format(date );
```

You can also use new DateTime API

```
     var formatted = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSS")
            .withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
            .format(Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis));
```

Comment: This would produce incorrect results for amounts of time more than a day. It would wrap the number of hours from 23 back to 0, which probably isn't desirable here.

Comment: No buddy... I think it would still work the same. try with today date

Comment: SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa"); 
in case someone wants in 12 hours format with am/pm

Answer (score 16):

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String formatted = df.format(aDateObject);
```

Comment: Same answer as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027317/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-hhmmss-format/24327049#24327049 with same problem for duration above 1 day

Comment: It's also dependent on time zone which means the result will differ when run in different time zones.

Answer (score 14):

this worked for me, with kotlin

```
fun formatToDigitalClock(miliSeconds: Long): String {
        val hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(miliSeconds).toInt() % 24
        val minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(miliSeconds).toInt() % 60
        val seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(miliSeconds).toInt() % 60
        return when {
            hours > 0 -> String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
            minutes > 0 -> String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
            seconds > 0 -> String.format("00:%02d", seconds)
            else -> {
                "00:00"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. This should be the best answer since it handles zero hour

Answer (score 11):

**Test results for the 4 implementations**

Having to do a lot of formatting for huge data, needed the best performance, so here are the (surprising) results:

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    FUNCTION_CALL
}

Durations:

- combinationFormatter: **196** millis
- formatDuration: **272** millis
- apacheFormat: 754 millis
- formatTimeUnit: 2216 millis

  ```
  public static String apacheFormat(long millis) throws ParseException {
      return DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(millis, "HH:mm:ss");
  }

  public static String formatTimeUnit(long millis) throws ParseException {
  String formatted = String.format(
          "%02d:%02d:%02d",
          TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
          TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)
                  - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
          TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis)
                  - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
      return formatted;
  }

  public static String formatDuration(final long millis) {
      long seconds = (millis / 1000) % 60;
      long minutes = (millis / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
      long hours = millis / (1000 * 60 * 60);

      StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
      b.append(hours == 0 ? "00" : hours < 10 ? String.valueOf("0" + hours) : 
      String.valueOf(hours));
      b.append(":");
      b.append(minutes == 0 ? "00" : minutes < 10 ? String.valueOf("0" + minutes) :     
      String.valueOf(minutes));
      b.append(":");
      b.append(seconds == 0 ? "00" : seconds < 10 ? String.valueOf("0" + seconds) : 
      String.valueOf(seconds));
      return b.toString();
  }

  public static String combinationFormatter(final long millis) {
      long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis)
              - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis));
      long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)
              - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis));
      long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis);

      StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
      b.append(hours == 0 ? "00" : hours < 10 ? String.valueOf("0" + hours) : 
      String.valueOf(hours));
      b.append(":");
      b.append(minutes == 0 ? "00" : minutes < 10 ? String.valueOf("0" + minutes) : 
      String.valueOf(minutes));
          b.append(":");
      b.append(seconds == 0 ? "00" : seconds < 10 ? String.valueOf("0" + seconds) : 
      String.valueOf(seconds));
      return b.toString(); 
   }
  ```

Comment: how reliable are metrics like these? I've never really understood the process.

Comment: In my situation where some thousands of objects are created in succession, this test I think is pretty useful. Okay not setting just some strings, but creating objects which have one field a formatted string.

Comment: @marius you went to the trouble to use `StringBuilder` then make the mistake of using "0"+number kind of "ruins" it. @mre JVM's GC is extremely good at allocating and collecting lots of short-lived objects, no worries there.  I went with `String.format` no leading-zero logic to deal with.

Answer (score 11):

### Java 9

```
    Duration timeLeft = Duration.ofMillis(3600000);
    String hhmmss = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", 
            timeLeft.toHours(), timeLeft.toMinutesPart(), timeLeft.toSecondsPart());
    System.out.println(hhmmss);
```

This prints:

> 01:00:00

You are doing right in letting library methods do the conversions involved for you. `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, or more precisely, its `Duration` class does it more elegantly and in a less error-prone way than `TimeUnit`.

The `toMinutesPart` and `toSecondsPart` methods I used were introduced in Java 9.

### Java 6, 7 and 8

```
    long hours = timeLeft.toHours();
    timeLeft = timeLeft.minusHours(hours);
    long minutes = timeLeft.toMinutes();
    timeLeft = timeLeft.minusMinutes(minutes);
    long seconds = timeLeft.toSeconds();
    String hhmmss = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
    System.out.println(hhmmss);
```

The output is the same as above.

### Question: How can that work in Java 6 and 7?

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) `java.time` comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 9):

The answer marked as correct has a little mistake,

```
String myTime = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) -
                    TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)), // The change is in this line
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) -
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
```

for example this is an example of the value that i get:

```
417474:44:19
```

This is the solution to get the right format is:

```
String myTime =  String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
                //Hours
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis) -
                        TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millis)),
                //Minutes
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) -
                        TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                //Seconds
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) -
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
```

getting as a result a correct format:

```
18:44:19
```

---

other option to get the format `hh:mm:ss` is just :

```
   Date myDate = new Date(timeinMillis);
   SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
   String myTime = formatter.format(myDate);
```

Answer (score 8):

Going by Bohemian's answer we need need not use TimeUnit to find a known value.
Much more optimal code would be

```
String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", millisLeft/(3600*1000),
                    millisLeft/(60*1000) % 60,
                    millisLeft/1000 % 60);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Like your answer the most! Just simple math. Btw in my case I added the milliseconds to the end `millisLeft%1000/10` so we get the format `hour:minutes:seconds:milliseconds`

Comment: @LêQuangDuy i need milliseconds in 3 digits like 01:24:51,123   but your is chopping 3 at last what to do ?

Comment: @naanu just use `millisLeft%1000`

Answer (score 8):

```
 public String millsToDateFormat(long mills) {

    Date date = new Date(mills);
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    String dateFormatted = formatter.format(date);
    return dateFormatted; //note that it will give you the time in GMT+0
}
```

Comment: Answer is dependent on time zone which means the result will differ when run in different time zones.

Answer (score 7):

```
        String string = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d",
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisecend), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisecend) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisecend)),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisecend) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisecend)), millisecend - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisecend)));
```

Format: 00:00:00.000

Example: 615605 Millisecend

00:10:15.605

Answer (score 5):

The code below does the conversion in both way

23:59:58:999 to 86398999

and than

86398999 to 23:59:58:999

---

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TimeUtility {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long currentDateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        String strTest = "23:59:58:999";
        System.out.println(strTest);

        long l = strToMilli(strTest);
        System.out.println(l);
        l += 1;
        String str = milliToString(l);
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    /**
     * convert a time string into the equivalent long milliseconds
     *
     * @param strTime string fomratted as HH:MM:SS:MSMS i.e. "23:59:59:999"
     * @return long integer like 86399999
     */
    public static long strToMilli(String strTime) {
        long retVal = 0;
        String hour = strTime.substring(0, 2);
        String min = strTime.substring(3, 5);
        String sec = strTime.substring(6, 8);
        String milli = strTime.substring(9, 12);
        int h = Integer.parseInt(hour);
        int m = Integer.parseInt(min);
        int s = Integer.parseInt(sec);
        int ms = Integer.parseInt(milli);

        String strDebug = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d:%03d", h, m, s, ms);
        //System.out.println(strDebug);
        long lH = h * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        long lM = m * 60 * 1000;
        long lS = s * 1000;

        retVal = lH + lM + lS + ms;
        return retVal;
    }

    /**
     * convert time in milliseconds to the corresponding string, in case of day
     * rollover start from scratch 23:59:59:999 + 1 = 00:00:00:000
     *
     * @param millis the number of milliseconds corresponding to tim i.e.
     *               34137999 that can be obtained as follows;
     *               <p>
     *               long lH = h * 60 * 60 * 1000; //hour to milli
     *               <p>
     *               long lM = m * 60 * 1000; // minute to milli
     *               <p>
     *               long lS = s * 1000; //seconds to milli
     *               <p>
     *               millis = lH + lM + lS + ms;
     * @return a string formatted as HH:MM:SS:MSMS i.e. "23:59:59:999"
     */
    private static String milliToString(long millis) {

        long hrs = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis) % 24;
        long min = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) % 60;
        long sec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) % 60;
        //millis = millis - (hrs * 60 * 60 * 1000); //alternative way
        //millis = millis - (min * 60 * 1000);
        //millis = millis - (sec * 1000);
        //long mls = millis ;
        long mls = millis % 1000;
        String toRet = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d:%03d", hrs, min, sec, mls);
        //System.out.println(toRet);
        return toRet;
    }
}
```

Comment: I upvoted this solution.  Just put a dot between sec and mls.  And I don't know why times and date handling is sooooo difficult in Java.  The most used functions should be already available and part of the class.

Answer (score 4):

I tried as shown in the first answer. It works, but minus brought me into confusion. My answer by Groovy:

```
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*

...

private static String formatElapsedTime(long millis) {

    int hrs = MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis) % 24
    int min = MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) % 60
    int sec = MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) % 60
    int mls = millis % 1000

    sprintf( '%02d:%02d:%02d (%03d)', [hrs, min, sec, mls])
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For Kotlin

```
val hours = String.format("%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milSecs))
val minutes = String.format("%02d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milSecs) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milSecs)))
val seconds = String.format("%02d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(milSecs) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milSecs)))
```

where, `milSecs` is milliseconds

Answer (score 2):

### In kotlin

```
private fun stringForTime(timeMs: Int): String {
    val totalSeconds = timeMs / 1000
    val seconds = totalSeconds % 60
    val minutes = totalSeconds / 60 % 60
    val hours = totalSeconds / 3600
    return if (hours > 0) {
        "%d:%02d:%02d".format(hours, minutes, seconds)
    } else {
        "%02d:%02d".format(minutes, seconds)
    }
}
```

### In Java

```
private String stringForTime(int timeMs) {
    int totalSeconds = timeMs / 1000;
    int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
    int minutes = totalSeconds / 60 % 60;
    int hours = totalSeconds / 3600;
    return hours > 0 ? String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
            "%d:%02d:%02d",
            hours,
            minutes,
            seconds) :
            String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                    "%02d:%02d",
                    minutes,
                    seconds);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could try something like this, :

```
public String getElapsedTimeHoursMinutesSecondsString() {       
     long elapsedTime = getElapsedTime();  
     String format = String.format("%%0%dd", 2);  
     elapsedTime = elapsedTime / 1000;  
     String seconds = String.format(format, elapsedTime % 60);  
     String minutes = String.format(format, (elapsedTime % 3600) / 60);  
     String hours = String.format(format, elapsedTime / 3600);  
     String time =  hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;  
     return time;  
 }
```

to convert milliseconds to a time value

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin:

```
fun FUNCTION_NAME(milliSeconds: Long): String {
    val s: Long = milliSeconds / 1000 % 60

    val m: Long = milliSeconds / (1000*60) % 60

    val h: Long = milliSeconds / (1000*60*60) % 24

    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", h, m, s)
}
```

Comment: This question asked in JAVA, you should answer it in Java please.

Comment: This question is 9 years old, and Kotlin is "designed to interoperate fully with Java", so I think this question could be expanded to allow for new technologies in the same sphere. Comments like this drive people away from SO.