# Timer to minutes : seconds : hundreds of seconds

Tags: java, timer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert milliseconds to “hh:mm:ss” format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027317/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-hhmmss-format)

I bet many people need a timer consisting of: `minutes : seconds : hundreds of seconds`.
Clearly you start with:

```
` public TimeGame(){

    timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            counter++;
        }
    });
    timer.start();
}`
```

And then you need to call a methode that transforms this counter in : `minutes : seconds : hundreds of seconds`.

```
`private String timeTransfer(){

     minutes = counter/6000;
     counter = counter - (minutes*6000);
     seconds = counter/100 ;
     counter = counter - (seconds*100);
     milliseconds = counter;
     return minutes + " : " + seconds + " : " + miliseconds;
 }`
```

Yet i have a bug in my method. once it reaches 100 milliseconds it jumps back to 0.
Normally it would have to put `0:1:0` , but it jumps back to `0:0:0`.
all Variables are declared private in the class.

So my question is does someone know a better method?

Comment: no duplicate, most timer converters are to hh:mm:ss

Comment: @MrMeThumbsUp Still duplicate as the concepts are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the cannonical form of this code, written many times by many people over many years:

```
private String timeTransfer(){

     minutes = counter/6000;
     seconds = (counter % 6000) /100 ;
     milliseconds = counter % 100;
     return minutes + " : " + seconds + " : " + milliseconds;
 }
```

Another poster commented that using the timer this way is inexact. If you are just running this thing for a couple of minutes, the errors won't add up too much. if you are doing more that a few minutes you will want to use the system time to handle this.

First you store the current time when you initialize your counter:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Then you periodically update the counter from the start time just before you return from `timeTransfer()`

```
if (milliseconds < 10) {
    counter = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 10;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Suggestions:

- Besides your math being off, a basic timer rule: do not trust the time interval of a Timer, ever. Instead store the initial System time, subtract it from the current System time and base your calculations on the real time, not on some artificial counter increment.
- Also, you're using *magic* numbers, and need to avoid them. Instead use constants such as SECONDS_PER_MINUTE and MINUTES_PER_HOUR which will help you avoid careless math errors.

Comment: Also `TimeUnit` is good at converting... time units... So for example: `long SECONDS_PER_MINUTE = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);`

Comment: @assylias: I never knew that even existed -- thanks!

Comment: <cough>[Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)<cough>

Comment: They said Java 7 would have Joda-Time equivalent 5 years ago. Now they say Java 8 will have it/has it.

Comment: @LeeMeador It is still on track for Java 8. The final set of feature should be crystallised at the end of January.

Answer (score 0):

Your method timeTransfer() modifies class member variable `counter`. Copy it to local variable in the beginning of method and perform calculations on it, for example:

```
    long counter = this.counter;
```