# Countdowntimer in minutes and seconds

Tags: java, android, eclipse

It's a countdown timer and i want to print in minutes and seconds. ex(300000mili)5 minutes, and count 4:60, 4:59...
here is part of my code

```
final MyCounter timer = new MyCounter(300000,1000);
    blue.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timer.start();
        }
    });
}
public class MyCounter extends CountDownTimer {

    public MyCounter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        blue.setText("Live");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        blue.setText((millisUntilFinished/60000)+":"+(millisUntilFinished/5000));
        // i tried this
    }
}
```

And how can i put to vibrate when missing 20 seconds? and when it finished?
thanks and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 73, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

```
TextView _tv = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.textView1 );
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) { // adjust the milli seconds here

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    _tv.setText(""+String.format("%d min, %d sec", 
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes( millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - 
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
    }

    public void onFinish() {
       _tv.setText("done!");
    }
 }.start();
```

Since java 1.5 there is the java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit class

```
 _tv.setText(""+String.format("%d min, %d sec", 
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes( millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - 
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html

A TimeUnit represents time durations at a given unit of granularity and provides utility methods to convert across units, and to perform timing and delay operations in these units.

For Java versions below 1.5 or for systems that do not fully support the TimeUnit class the following equations can be used:

```
int seconds = (int) (milliseconds / 1000) % 60 ;
int minutes = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000*60)) % 60);
int hours   = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
```

To vibrate

```
 Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
            v.vibrate(500);
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/> // permission in manifest
```

Edit:

Vibrate at 4 min 55 seconds for 500 milli seconds

```
 if((TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes( millisUntilFinished)==4) &&
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - 
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))==55)
            {

            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
            v.vibrate(500);
            }
```

Comment: And how can i put to vibrate when missing 20 seconds? and when it finished? thx

Comment: @LucaPimenta you need to find a way to compare and use the code in the edited answer

Comment: @Raghunandan hi bro. how r u? as u solve this problem. i have same problem. please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272345/how-to-start-new-countdowntimer-in-dialog-box-with-remaining-seconds

Comment: @Raghunandan great answer.

Comment: How can I show it with format mm:ss? Because if the elpased time is 8 sec, it show me: 0:8.

Comment: @FaustinoGagneten search for formatting long milli seconds in java

Comment: Following @Raghunandan suggestion about displaying the "0" in minutes and seconds like "00:08", I found this link, which worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027317/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-hhmmss-format

Answer (score 6):

Just use the modulo operator `%` to get the remaining milliseconds and divide by 1000 to convert to seconds.

```
blue.setText((millisUntilFinished / 60000)+":"+(millisUntilFinished % 60000 / 1000));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(duration, 1000) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        
                        mTextViewAdTime.setText("Ad: " + String.format("%02d:%02d",
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
                        
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        mTextViewAdTime.setText("Ad:");
                    }
                }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin version of Ashwin's answer:

```
var mCountDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(duration, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            val text = "OTP is valid for ${String.format(
                "%02d:%02d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(
                                millisUntilFinished
                            )
                        ))} minutes. Please enter the OTP "
            binding.timer.text = text
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            binding.timer.text = "Request OTP again to proceed."
        }
    }.start()
```